# atoi() returning 0 from char array

Tags: c

I am writing a program in which stdin is read into a buffer, then processed. The vast majority of these items that need to be processed are strings (or well, character arrays). However, I do have one item that needs to be read in as a character array and then converted to int for ease of use in the future.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    num[i] = buff[(i)];
    printf("%c", num[i]);
}

convert = atoi(num);
```

So I know for sure that the correct group of characters is being read into num because the printf for that is correct. However, when I try to print convert I end up getting 0, and I'm very perplexed as to what I'm doing wrong. I know that the 0 return means that a valid conversion could not be performed, but I don't know what's making it invalid. Any tips?

EDIT: Sorry for not including these before >_<

n is the number of chars in the buff array
buff is the buffer array stdin is read into

Comment: Can you give the inputs you are using?

Comment: Use [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead. It'll give you a pointer to the first character that couldn't be converted.

Comment: Any chance we can know what `n` and `buff` contain going into this? Kind of important.

Comment: I wonder if you're not copying the `NUL` character to terminate the C-string.

Comment: Is `num` properly `\0` terminated?

Comment: edited, sorry for not including earlier

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atoi` is a function that gives you no means to analyze error conditions. On top of that, it produces undefined behavior in overflow situations. Don't ever use `atoi` (or `atof` or anything from `ato...` group) in real-life programs. It is practically useless.

To perform string-to-number conversions use `strtol` (and other functions from `strto...` group).

Now, what is inside your `num` at the moment you call your `atoi`? Is your `num` properly zero-terminated?

Comment: If `n` is equal to `strlen(buff)` then they likely haven't copied the `NUL` terminator and `strtol` will also report an error.

Comment: What does `printf("%s\n", num);` look like?

Comment: @Austin Leigh: Strings in C have to be *zero terminated*. You need **seven** characters to represent string `303502` - six digits and `\0` at the end.

Comment: so I manually set num(i+1) = '\0' to be sure, but the error still occurs. Additionally, from the documentation suggested below, atoi should terminate at the \n character because it is non-numerical. Is it possible that there is a character that isn't being printed that's messing up the performance?

Comment: @Austin Leigh: If you want to zero-terminate your string after the above cycle, you have to set `num[i] = '\0'`. `num[i]`, not `num[i + 1]`. Or better just set `num[n] = '\0'`

Comment: yep that was the problem - I thought it was copying the \0 over but it wasn't. Thanks a lot; I'm just learning C strings and I keep missing silly things like that >_<