# Why Does My RGB To Hex Function Return 0 When Passing Color Components?

Tags: c++, colors, hex, rgb

//SOLUTION: Use bitwise operators and drop sstreams completely. atoi does not properly accept hex.//

```
namespace color_tools{

    std::stringstream sstream;

}

int RGB_256_to_hex(signed short r, signed short g, signed short b){

    std::string hex_col;

    color_tools::sstream << std::hex << r << g << b;

    hex_col = color_tools::sstream.str();

    color_tools::sstream.str("");

    color_tools::sstream.clear();

    return atoi(hex_col.c_str());

}
```

If I pass, for example, (0,0,255) then the function returns 0. This is not correct as the color blue is 0000ff. If I change the return type of the function to a string and just return hex_col I get the proper result. I'm assuming the issue must be with atoi()?

A bit off topic: Can I replace the signed short components with the __int8 type since this perfectly fits 256 color steps?

Miscellaneous suggestions would also be appreciated.

Comment: is atoi setting a error code to errno?

Comment: All problems aside, this function could (and should!) be written in *three* lines of code instead six, while still using the stringstream: `std::stringstream sstr; sstr << std::hex << r << g << b; return atoi(sstr.str().c_str());`.

Comment: If you only accept values between 0-255, you might as well use unsigned chars.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, atoi is the issue. It assumes that you've passed a decimal as its parameter, while you've passed a hexadecimal. It reads the digits until first non-digit (four zeros in your case) and returns the result.

I think that you'd better avoid this complex casting via streams and use simple bitwise operations like shifts and ORs, that will significantly improve readability, performance and simplicity of your code.

Comment: I will find a more elegant bitwise solution then.

Comment: By the way, if you think I answered your question, please mark it as a solution.