# Converting large string of numbers (14 digits) to integer or long in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, int, long-integer

I have a string that contains a 14-digit number.

I want to convert the string to an int.

When I use atoi(stringName), I get the max 32-bit in limitation.

Example:

String1 contains "201400000000"

```
long long tempNum1;
tempNum1 = atoi(String1);
printf("%d",tempNum1);
```

Output is: 2147483647

How can I turn this string into a number?  I want to compare it to other strings of numbers and find which is the largest.  (I have three strings of 14-digit numbers, I want to find which is the smallest, which is the largest).

Comment: I have to wonder what you were expecting `tempNum1 = sprintf(String1,NULL,10);` to do.

Comment: As could be guess from it's name [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) only deals with `int`. You might want to use [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Comment: it should be printf("%llu",tempNum1); 
and use strtoI for string to long conversion

Comment: `long` is still 32 bits on Windows and most 32-bit *nix OSes. Only `long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits

Comment: Thanks all.  strtoll works.  Also thanks @user2979190 for mentioning the format specifier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` returns an `int`.

That `int` is assigned to a `long long`, but by then the limit has already been reached.

You want to use `atoll` which returns a `long long`.

**And your printf format specifier is incorrect for your type.**

Comment: Thank youThank youThank you

Comment: And fix that format specifier else your compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: [`atoi()` and `atoll()` shoudn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 3):

Since your target is a `long long int`, you can use the [`strtoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long long tempNum1 = strtoll(String1, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using [strol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol):

```
long strtol (const char *Str, char **EndPoint, int Base)
```

or

```
long long strtoll( const char *restrict str, char **restrict str_end, int base );
```

The atoi says:

> The call atoi(str) shall be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> (int) strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10)
> ```
>
> except that the handling of errors may differ. **If the value cannot be
>   represented, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: That will fail on my 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 sscanf( String1, "%lld", &TempNum1);
```

Note that the format specifier %lld works for C99 , if not C99 please check the docs for the compiler