# Increase the value of an arithmetic type, stored in a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, increment, function-call

I program small devices, which communicate with each other and I need to label every action (and there are a lot) with an unique ID. Because of the architecture I can't use anything bigger than int (4 byte). So I had the idea to store the ID as a char array which I increment every time I call a certain function in a scenario like this:

```
void increaseIDByOne(char *ID){
  //increase "string"
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  char ID [12] = "00000000000";
  while(true){
    doStuff(&ID); 
    increaseIDByOne(&ID);
  }
}
```

The problem I have is, that I don't know how to manipulate the "string" without casting it temporarily to a arithmetic type. After reaching the value "99999999999" as an ID, the system then should have a solution, by allocating more space for the number or by using some other solution to prevent overflows or doubled IDs.
I hope that you can provide me with the right ideas, so I can find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Casting alone cannot make that string a number. You need to convert it properly. Just search `itoa()` and `atoi()`.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Increment_a_numerical_string#C

Comment: Do it with simple string manipulations, a bit like you did it in school when you were 11-12 years old.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment char arrays int values by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102127/increment-char-arrays-int-values-by-1)

Comment: @underscore_d this might overflow, his "string" has 11 digits.

Comment: Sure, but I leave such details as an exercise to the reader! The key point IMO is that this is hardly an unsolved problem for which searching cannot reveal adaptable solutions.

Comment: the problem is quite simplified with fixed length and non negative numbers

Comment: @underscore_d I mean converting it to `int` and back may be a problem, because with 11 digits this method will overflow for big numbers. The duplicate you suggested is OK

Comment: A 32-bit signed int can store more than two billion values/IDs. How many do you have?

Comment: The chosen answer in the linked question says, that the solution is not efficient for my problem.

Comment: i am writing a solution for your problem

Comment: @schande solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of negative numbers made the problem quite simpler. Simplr use `realloc` whenever there is a chance of overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increaseIDByOne(char *ID){
  //increase "string"
  size_t len = strlen(ID);
  int all9 = 1;
  //int carry = 0;
  for(size_t i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    if(ID[i]=='9')
        continue;
    else
    {
        all9 = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(all9)
  {
    ID = realloc(ID, len + 2);
    ID[len] = '0';
  }
  len = strlen(ID);
  for(size_t i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    if(ID[i]=='9')
    {
        ID[i] = '0';
    }
    else if(ID[i]<'9')
    {
        ID[i]++;
        return;
    }
    //printf("%c\n", ID[i]);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *ID = malloc(12);
  strcpy(ID, "99999999995");
  while(1){
    //doStuff(&ID); 
    increaseIDByOne(ID);
    printf("%s\n",ID);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
99999999996
99999999997
99999999998
99999999999
999999999991
999999999992
999999999993
999999999994
999999999995
999999999996
999999999997
999999999998
999999999999
9999999999991
9999999999992
9999999999993
9999999999994
9999999999995
9999999999996
9999999999997
9999999999998
9999999999999
99999999999991
99999999999992
99999999999993
99999999999994
99999999999995
99999999999996
99999999999997
99999999999998
99999999999999
and so on...
```

Comment: Nope, the PO want to have memory allocation in case of overflow ;) Even if it's "useless" since it can go on "overflow" for quite a time.

Comment: nope, the memory is fixed. the OP doesn;t want memory allocation

Comment: Quoting PO : After reaching the value "99999999999" as an ID, the system then should have a solution, by allocating more space for the number or by using some other solution to prevent overflows or doubled IDs.

Comment: Well, no. What come after "99999999999" is not "999999999991" but "100000000000". You're not so far ;)

Comment: I think that's irrelevant if we are going to use it as an id, but that will be logical. I will edit it as soon as I am free.

Answer (score 0):

This is one implementation possible :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct id {
    char   *str;
    size_t strLen;
} id_s;

#define ID_CONSTRUCTOR {.str    = NULL,\
                        .strLen = 0}

void Id_Constructor(id_s *self)
{
    id_s tmp = ID_CONSTRUCTOR;

    *self = tmp;
}

void Id_Destructor(id_s *self)
{
    free(self->str);
}

bool Id_Init(id_s *self, size_t nbDigit)
{
    // Checking (assert ?)
    if (nbDigit == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : nbDigit can't be 0.\n", __func__);
        return (false);
    }
    // Memory allocation
    free(self->str);
    if (!(self->str = malloc(nbDigit + 1))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : malloc(nbDigit + 1) : nbDigit=%zu, errno='%s'.\n", __func__, nbDigit, strerror(errno));
        return (false);
    }
    // initialization
    self->strLen = nbDigit;

    self->str[0] = self->strLen == 1 ? '0' : '1';
    for (size_t i = 1; i < self->strLen; ++i) {
        self->str[i] = '0';
    }
    self->str[self->strLen] = '\0';

    return (true);
}

bool Id_Increment(id_s *self)
{
    char *idTmp;

    for (int i = self->strLen - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (self->str[i] == '9') {
            self->str[i] = '0';
        } else {
            ++self->str[i];
            return (true);
        }
    }

    if (!(idTmp = realloc(self->str, self->strLen + 2))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : realloc(self->str, self->strLen + 2) : self->str='%s', self->strLen=%zu, errno='%s'.\n", __func__, self->str, self->strLen, strerror(errno));
        return (false);
    }
    self->str = idTmp;
    self->str[0] = '1';
    self->str[self->strLen] = '0';
    self->str[self->strLen + 1] = '\0';
    ++self->strLen;
    return (true);
}

int main (void)
{
    id_s id = ID_CONSTRUCTOR;

    if (!Id_Init(&id, 1)) {
        printf("Unable to initialize id.\n");
        return (1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", id.str);
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i){
        Id_Increment(&id);
        printf("%s\n", id.str);
    }

    Id_Destructor(&id);
    return (0);
}
```