# How to stop user entering char as int input in C

Tags: c, user-input

Heres a part of my code:

```
    printf("\nEnter amount of adult tickets:");
    scanf("%d", &TktAdult);
    while (TktAdult<0){
        printf("\nPlease enter a positive number!");
        printf("\nEnter amount of adult tickets:");
        scanf("%d", &TktAdult);
    }
```

Right now it can only stop user from entering a negative value, but how do I add to it so it also stops user from entering a char??

Comment: Read the data to a char* buffer, and parse it.

Comment: have you tried with atoi? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm

Comment: @HRgiger don't suggest atoi, it is old unsafe and hard to use.

Comment: @HRgiger https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf what was wrong with my question sir? :/

Comment: a %d format specifier will not allow a character to be entered..   Note the logic of the posted code is rather convoluted.  But most of all, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) of any call to any of the `scanf()` family of functions to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest reading the `man` page for `scanf()`  to get all the details, but of current interest is the `returned value` paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code rejects user input that are:

- non-numeric as handled by // 1;
- negative numbers as handled by // 2;
- positive numbers followed by non-numeric chars as handled by //3

  ```
   while (1) {
       printf("\nEnter amount of adult tickets: ");
       if (scanf("%d", &TktAdult) < 0 ||  // 1
               TktAdult < 0 ||  // 2
               ((next = getchar()) != EOF && next != '\n')) {  // 3
           clearerr(stdin);
           do
               next = getchar();
           while (next != EOF && next != '\n');  // 4
           clearerr(stdin);
           printf("\nPlease enter a positive number!");
       } else {
           break;
       }
   }
  ```

Also, // 4 clears the standard input of buffered non-numeric characters following case // 3 (i.e. 123sda - scanf takes 123 but leaves 'sda' in the buffer).

Comment: Except that scanf("%d", &TktAdult) returns a negative value and not a 0 for non-numeric input. Yup, next is declared on top of that while along with declaration of TktAdult. It's just a code snippet with the declarations taken out. Anyway, I've tested that code already for all 3 cases before posting it. So I'm pretty confident it works.

Answer (score 5):

> ... stop user from entering a negative value ...

is not possible.  Users enter all sorts of gibberish.  Instead, read a *line* of user input and parse it for correctness.  Use `fgets()` for input, then  `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc. for parsing.

```
// return -1 on EOF
int GetPositiveNumber(const char *prompt, const char *reprompt) {
  char buf[100];
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  fflush(stdout);
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) [
    int value;
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &value) == 1 && value > 0) {
      return value;
    }
    fputs(reprompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  return -1;
}

// Usage
int TktAdult = GetPositiveNumber(
    "\nEnter amount of adult tickets:" , 
    "\nPlease enter a positive number!");
if (TktAdult < 0) Handle_End_of_File();
else Success(TktAdult);
```

Comment: `getline()` is more useful than `fgets()`, since it can allocate the needed buffer. The problem however is that `fgets()` might be less portable.

Comment: @glauxosdever `getline()` is not part of the standard C library.  `fgets()` is part of the standard C library making `fgets()` _more  portable_ than  `getline()`.  `getline()` has a weakness as it allows the hacker exploit of overwhelming computer resources based on user input.  Numeric input exceeding 100 characters is certainly an error or attack.  Code only needs to process the data in those cases, not allocate large memory.

Comment: Clearly a typo. I definitely meant `getline()` is less portable and not `fgets()`.

Comment: To be fair, while I'm concerned much about security, I didn't ever think `getline()` could be exploitable this way. Good catch!

Comment: @glauxosdever I like `getline()` over `fgets()` for _file_ input, not `stdin`, but even that is getting exploitable.  If a `getline_s()` existed with an upper bound, that would be good, yet then that is similar to`fgets()` with a pre-allocated buffer.    IMO, a robust user input function is not possible simple using current functions given todays nefarious users.  Feel like using `fgetc()` is the only safe building block.  Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

> but how do I add to it so it also stops user from entering a char??

You can't prevent user from entering character values. What you can do is check if `tktAdult` was successfully scanned.
If not, flush out everything from stdin:

```
 bool valid = false;
 while (true) {
 ...

    if (scanf("%d", &TktAdult) != 1) {
       int c;
       while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
    } else {
       break;
    }
}
```

The better alternative is to use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and then parse the line using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Also see: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest use of scanf either since it's hard to use and error-prone compared to `fgets` + `strtoull`

Comment: @cat I suggested it too and the link explains it very well. `sscanf()` approach works just as well as `strtoull`. I suppose copy-pasteable code is valued more on SO.

Comment: I tried this... but it still accepts numeric input immediately followed by non-numeric characters as valid (i.e. 123sda is accepted as 123). Hence, I added a bit of additional code taking off from this one.

Answer (score 3):

```
// You can try this,  Filter all except for the digital characters
int TktAdult;
char ch;
char str[10];
int i = 0;
printf("\nEnter amount of adult tickets:");
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    // Filter all except for the digital characters
    if(!isalpha(ch) && isalnum(ch))
        str[i++] = ch;
}
str[i] = '\0';
TktAdult = atoi(str);
printf("Done [%d]\n", TktAdult);
```

Comment: Better to use `int ch` than `char ch` to prevent UB in the `is...()` calls and to detect `EOF` (which causes an infinite loop here).  Suggest adding a limit to the number of iterations in `while()` so `i` does not get too big.

Comment: Please, don't suggest atoi. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0.0;
    int readReasult;
    while(1)
    {
        readReasult = scanf("%d",&x);
        if (readReasult < 0) break;
        if (readReasult == 1) {
            if (x >= 0)
                printf("next number: %d\n", x);
            else
                printf("negative value not expected\n");
        } else {
            clearerr(stdin);
            scanf("%*s");
            printf("wrong input\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xn86qz