# Why we need getchar() although using scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

this code should read a positive number and if user enter a non-numeric value, it asking him again to enter a number and wait the input to check again till entering a number

```
 do
   {
        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
   }
  while ( (scanf("%d%c", &n,&c) != 2 || c!='\n' || n<0) ) ;
```

but actually when entering non-numeric it keeps doing the body of the while loop without reading the waiting to check the condition of the while loop `while(scanf("%d%c", &n,&c) != 2 || c!='\n' || n<0)`

when edit the condition to

```
int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1;
}

 do
   {
        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
   }
  while ( (scanf("%d%c", &n,&c) != 2 || c!='\n' || n<0) && clean_stdin() ) ;
```

It executes in the right way, but I don't understand why we need to add `getchar()` although we already use `scanf()` in the condition

Comment: `getch` is not standard, Your code does not use it anyway.

Comment: Although `%d` format cleans off any leading whitespace in the input buffer, the `clean_stdin` is needed to take care of the case when you entered say `123z`.

Comment: Why I use fseek is that you can break input with CTRL-D. So you can't call getchar() to wait "\n".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `scanf("%d%c", ...` encounters non-numeric input, the `"%d"` causes the scanning to stop and the offending character to remain in `stdin` for the next input function.  The `"%c"` does not get a chance to read that non-numeric character.

If code re-reads `stdin` with the same `scanf("%d%c", ...`, the same result.  Some *other* way is needed to remove the non-numeric input.  `getchar()`, `getch()`, etc. will read any 1 character.

[Example code `GetPositiveNumber()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146306/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using fgets to collect input. Any invalid input is already removed from the input stream making it simpler to try again.
Parse the input with sscanf or others as needed.

```
char input[40] = "";
int valid = 0;
int n = 0;

do {
    printf ( "Enter a positive integer\n");
    if ( fgets ( input, sizeof ( input), stdin)) {
        int last = 0;
        if ( 1 == ( valid = sscanf ( input, "%d%n", &n, &last))) {
            if ( n < 0  || input[last] != '\n') {
                valid = 0;//reset if negative or last is not newline
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input from fgets\n");
        return 0;
    }
} while ( valid != 1);
```

Comment: my bad, no problem with EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Because `scanf()` with most specifiers ignores white spaces, and you need to collect them before calling `scanf()` again if a `'\n'` is left in the buffer. If you don't collect them (*and discard them immediately*), then `scanf()` will return immediately on the next call.

Comment: Not true. The `%d` format specifier cleans off all leading whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please try to simply `while (((count = scanf("%d", &value)) != 1) && (count != EOF))`, what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

See this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char c = 0;
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

If you type over two or three characters, second call of scanf doesn't work as interructive. And getch() is not standard. Also you shouldn't call getchar() since it may block. <del>You can use fseek</del>.

Hack using fseek works only on Windows. :-(

### BAD SOLUTION

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char c = 0;
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

### GOOD SOLUTION

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  char c = 0;
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  while (!feof(stdin) && getchar() != '\n');
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%c\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

This works good on Windows & Linux

Comment: Using `fseek()` on a terminal on a Unix-like system does nothing; terminals are not seekable devices.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I works only on Windows. How about use `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0); setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);` ?

Comment: For my money, use `getchar()` until newline (or EOF).  If that's not OK, then pretty much any solution is platform-specific.  Platform-specific isn't a problem as long as the platform(s) where it works is (are) clearly identified.  Don't present a platform-specific solution as a universal solution.  Sometimes, though, you're aren't aware in advance that a solution _is_ platform-specific.  For example, Microsoft supports `fflush(stdin)`; Unix-like systems do not.  Microsoft may support the `fseek()` on terminal input streams; Unix-like systems do not.  If you aren't aware of this, it's hard.

Comment: updated post. and it seems that checking feof at first is better for me.

Comment: Instead of checking `feof()` after using `c`, recommend checking the return value of `scanf()` - it it 1?

Comment: even though scanf return 1, buffer will be filled with rest characters.

Comment: Hmm, Window support rewind(stdin), but Windows doesn't support select(fileno(stdin)). Maybe platform-compatible solution not exists.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &c);` can return `EOF`.  Then `printf("%c\n", c);` is undefined behavior.  Better to check the return value of `scanf()` first before using `c`.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong), but you're using a slightly different construct which is 'OK'.  I'd still prefer: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` if only because it is one function call, not two.