# Convert from char * to int

Tags: c, casting

I have a string char * a = '343'. I want to convert it into integer value.

Example.
char *a = "44221"
I want to store that value into into int a;

Comment: `'343'` is not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help

```
#include <stdlib.h>

inline int to_int(const char *s)
{
    return atoi(s);
}
```

just in case for an example usage

```
int main( int ac, char *av[] )
{
    printf(" to_int(%s) = %d " ,av[1] , to_int(av[1]) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -blinks twice at that wrapper-

Answer (score 4):

This is is part of most C runtimes:

```
#include <stdlib>

char *a = "1234";
int i = atoi(a);
```

That's the [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function. Do read through the various methods available. C's library is pretty lean so it won't take long.

Comment: [`atoi` is harmful](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/03/13/atol-considered-harmful/) and [shouldn't be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to convert a string (pointed at by a `char *`) into an `int`:

I'm listing few of them here: 
Let's assume you have a string `str` declared as:

```
char *str = "44221";
```

1. **int a = atoi(str);** 
   This returns the `int` value converted from the string pointed at by `str`. Although convenient, this function does not perform accurate error reporting when user supplies an invalid input.
2. **Using sscanf():** This is similar to the usual `scanf` except that it reads input from a string rather than from `stdin`.

   ```
   int a;
   int v = sscanf(str, "%d", &a);
   // XXX: v should be 1 since 1 conversion is performed; handle the conversion error if it isn't
   ```
3. **strtol**: This converts a given string to a long integer. Documentation found at: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

   General usage:

   ```
   char *ptr; 
   long a = strtol(str, &ptr, base);
   ```

The address of the first invalid character (not a digit) is stored in `ptr`. Base is by default 10.

4. **Iterating through character values:** Why depend on libraries when you can write your own routine to achieve this? It isn't hard at all. That way you can even perform the required validation/error checking.

   Sample code:

   ```
   unsigned char ch;   
   int a = 0;
   // Add checks to see if the 1st char of the string is a '+' or '-'.
   for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) { 
       ch = str[i]; 
      //Add error checks to see if ch is a digit or not (e.g. using isdigit from <ctype.h>).
       a = a*10 + (ch - '0');
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!