# Converting String from strftime to int/long

Tags: c

The goal is a function, that delivers an int (or long) with the actual time.
I therefor write the localtime into a string (as far as I understood this) and try to convert it with atoi/atol into my int/long. But somehow I don't get the expected result.

Things I've tried:

- I switched from the initial int to long.
- I changed the size of my string. If I resize it to 7 instead of my needed 15 bytes, it converts at least the date part of my string. But I need it all.

I've got the following code:

```
long generate_time()
{    
    time_t time1;
    time(&time1);

    char time_str[15];
    long act_time;

    strftime(time_str, 15, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime(&time1));
    printf("Actual time: %s\n", time_str);

    act_time = atol(time_str);
    printf("Transformed time: %d\n", act_time);

    return act_time;
}
```

Resulting in the response:

> Actual time: 20170407091221
>   Transformed time: 1240669205

I hope this is easy to sort out and thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: You should translate your code to English before to post your question. Users can help you better if understand what you wrote...

Comment: do you want to return the time in the timestamp format as long? returning 20170407091221 as integer value makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've changed it.

Comment: [you shouldn't use `atol`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: Use `long long` instead of `long` like [this](http://ideone.com/UWIXk7)

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a long to store such data: max value for `signed long` is:

```
-2^31+1 to +2^31-1
```

or

```
-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
```

You can use `unit64_t` to do what you need

```
#include <stdint.h>

[...]

uint64_t act_time = strtoll(time_str, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

`atol` converts a string into a `long` which in your case probably is 32 bits and thus cannot hold the value `20170407091221`. Your value `1240669205` is the lower 32 bits of `20170407091221`.

You can easily check that with for example `calc.exe` on Windows:
20170407091221 as hex: 1258 49F3 1C15
1240669205 as hex: 49F3 1C15

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there any way to change the limitation?

Comment: @MathiasWoellm compile it for 64 bit might work - it would on Mac OS. Or use a `long long` and [strtoll()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll)