# conversion between types in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I come from other programming languages and I don't understand why this code throws error.

```
string n = "123456";
int x;

for(int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {

    x = atoi( n[i].c_str() );
    x *= 2;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Can you explain me this accident? And show me how to convert it into integer properly?

Comment: What is `n[i]`? Is it a `std::string` object? Did you really *read* the error message (whatever it is)? Perhaps you should [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start learning C++ properly?

Comment: `n[i]` is a char. (Not a `string` of size 1). `char` does not have member functions.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve - do you want to convert the entire number described by your string to an `int` (in which case you'd simply use `x = std::stoi(n);` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) or do you want to perform some calculation with each digit of that number?

Comment: [don't use `atoi`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714). It's [harmful](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/03/13/atol-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [return type of `std::basic_string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at): it's `reference` or `const_reference`. That is, a (const) reference to a *character*. In the case of `std::string`, it means you get a reference to a `char`, not a `std::string`.

C++ guarantees that the character values of digits are sequential and increasing. In other words, it's guaranteed that `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'2' - '0' == 2` and so on, regardless of character encoding used. So the way to convert the `char` containing a digit into the digit's value is to do just this:

```
x = n[i] - '0';
```

Comment: In case someone is wondering over the `char` to integer promotion in the final snippet, the `'0'` subtraction simply shifts the ASCII value of `n[i]` by `48`, since character values of digits starts (and, as mentioned above, continuous sequentially, increasing) at ASCII value `48` (for `'0'`).

Comment: @dfri It shifts the value of `n[i]` by the value of the literal `'0'`. That is 48 when the system is using ASCII, but it can be anything else in other encodings. The point is that it must always work such that `'1' - '0' == 1` (and similar for other digits).

Comment: I didn't consider non-ASCII systems, thanks for the clarification! Your comment above (especially core-point the last sentence) might valuable to include in the answer for those of us that didn't entirely catch this.