# Replace $n with n in string

Tags: c

My program will receive a command like

> ./a.out echo $3 $1 ">" log.txt

i need to replace the $3 with 3 and 1 to use latter when reading from stdin, at this moment i have my code like this (its only doing for one $n at this moment):

```
int total = argc-1;
int coluna =0;
int i,n,cut,s, pid,status;
char *cmd[total]; 
char buffer[PIPE_BUF];
char col[10];
char field[10];


//passar argumentos para array
for(i=0;i<total;i++) {
    if(i+1 == total) cmd[total+1] = NULL;
    else cmd[i] = argv[i+1];
}
//verify for $n
char *tmp = cmd;
for(i=0;i<total-1;i++) {
    if(sscanf(tmp,"[$]%s",col) == 1) coluna = atoi(col);
}
```

the code executes everything else is working (tried without $n, and some other test), but i'm not getting the correct results, seems it ignores the value.

can someone point me my error?

Comment: A complete minimal working example would be great...I am also not sure what is the problem in he behavior (what works and what doesn't, by your sayings).

Comment: Did you check `argc`?  Typically, if you type `a.out echo $3 $1`  it is the same typing just `a.out echo`, since the `$3` and the `$1` will each be replaced with the empty string and no argument will be passed.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. What do you want to do with the args after? Can you show that code. *the code executes everything else is working), but i'm not getting the correct results*. What is the expected output, what are you getting? Provide a Minimal, verifiable and reproducible example.

Comment: @WilliamPursell wow, never thought that might be the problem, will check it, i put "$n" to try, but will check if that isn't the problem, because when i tested printing the array it only gave me the argumentos without $:

Comment: @gsamaras it will do a loop readin from stdin, fork to a child, read stdin from father a string separated by columns, use the $n column to execute the program on the child and return the exit status to father.

didn't include that because my problem is getting the number without the $.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya expected output would be coluna getting the int n from $n.

Comment: Okay, found the problem, the sscanf is not producing the expect results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeatedly overwrite `coluna`:

```
for(...)
{
    if(sscanf(...) == 1)
        coluna = atoi(col); // <--
}
```

I cannot figure out what you exactly want to achive, if you just want to get the *first* such value (thus the name "coluna"?), then simply `break` your loop:

```
if(sscanf(...) == 1)
{
    coluna = atoi(col);
    break;
}
```

Otherwise, use coluna directly here instead of breaking or store your values in an array as below. Assuming every argument might contain `$n`:

```
int cols[argc-1]; // assuming you checked for argc > 1 already!
int numCols = 0;

if(sscanf(...) == 1)
    cols[numCols++] = atoi(col);
```

Side note: These two pieces of code:

```
int total = argc-1;

for(i=0;i<total;i++) {
    if(i+1 == total) cmd[total+1] = NULL;
    else cmd[i] = argv[i+1];
}
```

can be replaced by simply doing:

```
--argc;
++argv;
```

unless you really need for any reason a copy (like comparing modified cmd against original argv). If you modify argc/argv as above, you can then use argc and argv just as you do with cmd/total. To retain the names, you might even rename argc to total and argv to cmd...

Comment: [`atoi` has deprecated and shouldn't be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Sure - I don't use it myself anyway, just retained it because of being in the original question...

Comment: @Aconcagua i want the value(s) of coluna to use later with an input string to extract the nth field.