# Contiki Timestamp value as int

Tags: c, timer, sensors, iot, contiki

I would like to send the value of the timestamp of a simulation as int. To be more clear, if the mote output is:

```
00:39.841   ID:6    unicast message ready to be sent
```

I want to be able to put in my message the value 00:39.841 in milliseconds. How can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried with RTIMER_NOW(), but it returns a value of rtimer_clock_t type and I need int. My goal is to be able to distinguish at the Receiver which message has been prepared later than the other

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use function [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to find string you need i.e. `00` or `39`.

and [`strtol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to conversion from string to long integer. Anyway, stay **away** from `atoi()`.

[Why shouldn't one use atoi()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi).

Here is example, convertion from minutes/seconds to miliseconds is up to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[] = "00:39.841   ID:6    unicast message ready to be sent";
    char * ptr;


    long minutes  = 0,
         seconds  = 0,
         milisecs = 0;

    ptr     = strtok(input, ":");
    if (ptr == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input minutes."); return 1; }
    minutes = strtol(ptr, (char **)NULL, 10);

    ptr     = strtok(&input[3], ".");
    if (ptr == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input seconds."); return 1; }
    seconds = strtol(ptr, (char **)NULL, 10);

    ptr     = strtok(&input[6], " ");
    if (ptr == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input milisecs."); return 1; }
    milisecs = strtol(ptr, (char **)NULL, 10);

    printf("%ld - %ld - %ld\n", minutes, seconds, milisecs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, but I don't need this, the mote output comes from Cooja and I want to be able to access the time

Comment: So get output from Cooja, store it and then convert it like i did ? `char * input = CoojaOutput` Thats exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yes, but in this way I have to access the text script, and I want to avoid, I would like to use functions like RTIMER_NOW() ad so on. Thank you

Comment: maybe a function like clock_second() but getting millisec could be better..

Comment: Then multiply seconds * 1000 and youve got miliseconds.

Comment: So maybe its time to create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since your question doesnt contain much informations.