# Why 2D array always print out 0 in C?

Tags: c, arrays

This is my first programming in C. In printGrid() function, I tried to assign some values to the 2D array, and the rest spots in the 2D array just assign 0. I test it as soon as the value is assigned to an array and it works as expected. However, when I use display() function to print out the whole array, it did not work correctly, all the values in the array are 0. I have spent several hours to do the search and debugged it by myself before I post a question here. Could someone help me with this question? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int max_height = 4;

int height; //the height of pile
int center_x_index, center_y_index; //index of input parameter that is center of the plane
int unstable;
int drop_status;
int *grid[5][5];


int is_stable(int total_param, char *piles[]);
void display(int *grid[5][5]);

/*
Function to print out the 23*23 grid with given number of piles
*/

void printGrid(int total_param, char *piles[])
{
    int i, j, k, size, assigned;
    size = 5;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            for (k = 1; k < total_param; k = k + 3)
            {
                if ((atoi(piles[k]) == i) && (atoi(piles[k + 1]) == j))
                {
                    height = atoi(piles[k + 2]);

                    //find the central pile of the plane and drop a grain of sand onto this pile.
                    if ((i == j) && i == (size / 2))
                    {
                        center_x_index = k;
                        center_y_index = k + 1;
                        if (drop_status > 0 && is_stable(total_param, piles))
                        {
                            drop();
                        }

                    }
                    grid[i][j] = &height; //store value into 2D array
                    //printf("2D array: %d", *grid[i][j]);
                    printf("%d", height);
                    assigned = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    assigned = 0;
                }


            }
            if (assigned != 1)
            {
                height = 0;
                grid[i][j] = &height;
                printf("%d", 0);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");


    }

}


void display(int *grid[5][5])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", *grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    printGrid(argc, argv);

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: since `&height` is always same value, `grid[i][j] = &height` won't work as you expect.

Comment: Add sample of command line and output expected to post. (`center = (char)(atoi(argv[center_x_index + 2])-4);
      argv[center_x_index + 2] = &center;` : I don’t think that it works properly even if what is expected.)

Comment: please indent your code and try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a whole program. Besides, [don't use `atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: `grid[i][j] = &height;` because of this. All your pointers are pointing to the same global variable. You will see the value that was last stored in height.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to study up on pointers in C. See [this](https://web.stanford.edu/~fringer/teaching/operating_systems_03/handouts/lecture9.pdf) for example.

This line

```
int *grid[5][5];
```

declares a 2D array of *pointers* to integers.

This line

```
grid[i][j] = &height; //store value into 2D array
```

stores the *address* of the variable `height` to that `grid` element. At that point in time `height` is the value you expect, but on the next iteration of the loop you will overwrite it.

So at the end you will have every element in `grid` pointing to the same variable `height`. This line

```
printf("%d", *grid[i][j]);
```

*dereferences* the pointer at `grid[i][j]`, that is, it follows the pointer to the variable `height` and uses its value. Since at this point in time `height` is zero and every `grid` element points to it, this will print out all zeros.

What you need to do is instead declare `grid` as a 2D array of `int`:

```
int grid[5][5];
```

assign the value of `height` to it instead of its address:

```
grid[i][j] = height; //store value into 2D array
```

and use its value directly instead of dereferencing it:

```
printf("%d", grid[i][j]);
```

There are probably some other pieces of code you'll have to update as well after changing the definition of `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

This line declares a two-dimensional array of int *pointers*:

`int *grid[5][5];`

I think you just wanted a two-dimensional array of *integers*:

`int grid[5][5];`

The problem is that when you assign the pointer `&height` to one of these pointers, it assigns the same thing to every one of them; the address of your `height` variable. When you change `height` after assigning it to the array, you will change the value that will appear in every single slot in the array, since they're all referencing the original `height` variable. If you use a two-dimensional array of integers instead, and just assign `height`, then the value will be copied and you will avoid this problem.