# Pass argument to main function with command line but the value is always 2

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, command-line-arguments

This is my main function code

**os2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
 int item;
 item = argc;
 printf("%d", item);

 return 0;
}
```

> I run the following command line in Ubuntu's terminal

`gcc -o test os2.c` 
`./test 5`

The result printed is equal to **2** instead of 5, What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I suggest you read some [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Answer (score 3):

First, your question is not just for Ubuntu/Linux.
It works in Windows and Macintosh too including every OS using the terminal.

**`argc`** = argument count: the number of argument that are passed to a program
**`argv`** = argument vector: passed arguments

`argc` is an `int` that count the arguments of your command line.

> I run the following command line in Ubuntu's terminal: `gcc -o test os2.c`
>   `./test 5`

Here your arguments are

1. argv[0] == `./test`
2. argv[1] == `5`

So we conclude that:

**`argc`** is 2 based on the number of arguments above.
**`argv`** contains the arguments that we've passed to the program.

This is an example of how you use arguments in the right way:

**source.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    for(int i = 0;i < argc;i++)
        printf("arg %d : %s\n",i,argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Command Line**

```
gcc -o test source.c
./test this is a test
```

**Output**

```
arg 0 : ./test
arg 1 : this
arg 2 : is
arg 3 : a
arg 4 : test
```

But anyways, I recommend to never use the first argument; It'd be a gap in your software cause it can be hacked easily. There're many ways to do whatever you want in C.

**Now**; You should know what you've to do if you want to get the value **`5`** instead of *counting* the number of arguments that you've passed to your application which in the *OP* case were *`2`*.

Comment: `argv` is often regarded as short for 'argument vector' — it is an array of strings.  'Argument values' more or less works as a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with code. You are passing two arguments `./test` and `5`. So it shows 2. It is the number of arguments passed to the program.

`argc` : argument count.

To get the argument passed you can do this.

```
printf("%s",argv[1]);
```

In general you check it like this:

```
if(argc!=2)
{
  printf("Usage: ./program-name argument\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE; // failure-considering you are writing this in main.
}
// do your work here.
```

But in `argv[1]` you will get the char string. To get an integer out of it, you have to convert it using something like `atoi` or your custom conversion function. Also you can use [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) which is useful in conversion from string to long.

<sub>1. In case of `main` `return EXIT_FAILURE` works but not in other functions but `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` works in all the functions</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`argc` means the number of argument that are passed to the program. not printed which value you have passed.

Use `argv[1]` to print value of `5`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc >= 2)
    printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`argc` (*argument count*) and `argv` (*argument vector*) are how command line arguments are passed to `main()` in C and C++.

`argc` is number of arguments passed to program (number of strings pointed to by `argv`), which is correct in your case. First string is program name, second string is `"5"` (so you have to convert `"5"` to `int`).

**[This might be a useful reading for you.](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html)**

---

If you want to convert second argument to `int` try this

```
if (argc < 2)
{
    return -1;
}

int item = atoi(argv[1]);
```

[`atoi` may lead to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi) so you should use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) instead.

Or you may loop through all arguments

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    // argv[i] is the argument at index i
    // You may print them
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
    // Convert them, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argc` is the count of arguments, which is 2 here. If you intend to print 5, you need to print `argv[1]` (or if you always want the last argument, `argv[argc-1]`) instead.