# How to convert a part of a string into int in C?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, int, atoi

I have a code line as follows,

```
char conv[20]="score: 34";
```

I want to extract the number(34) inside the 'conv' string and convert it into and integer. I used 'atoi' function. But it give 0 as the result.

```
printf("score: %d\n",atoi(conv)); //this prints 'score: 0'
```

Could someone help me to convert the number inside that string into an integer?

Comment: Functions like `atoi()` only work if the string is a pure number. You must first find the number. You can do this using a function like [strpbrk(conv,"0123456789")](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strpbrk).

Comment: And to get a little further in the weeds, you would need to include `+-` as chars that can begin the string to convert and check that the next character is `0-9`. Also recommend `strtol` instead of `atoi`, `atoi` provides no way to validate a successful conversion has taken place.

Comment: You could also do `sscanf(conv, "score: %d", &n);` if you know the string has that format.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use `atoi()?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @TomKarzes It works.. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

`atoi()` will return `0` if conversion cannot be performed. Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

The string `"score: 34"` cannot be converted to a valid `int`. So `atoi()` returns `0`.

If there's nothing else after the `34` in your string, you could do

```
printf("score: %d\n",atoi(conv + 7));
```

This would give `34`. `conv + 7` points to the string `"34"`. It is equivalent of `conv + strlen("score: ")`.

Use of [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of `atoi()` might be better here.

You can find what exactly went wrong more easily with `strtol()`.

You could use it like

```
long rv=strtol(conv, &ptr, 10);
```

where `ptr` is of type `char *` or just

```
rv=strtol(conv, NULL, 10);
```

If `conv` is `"score: 34"` here, `0` is returned and `ptr` will point to start of `conv`.

Note that `strtol()` returns a `long` and not an `int`.

If the range of `int` is less than that of `long`, you may want to check if the returned value is greater than the biggest `int` which is `INT_MAX` for signed int. `INT_MAX` is in `limits.h`.

If overflow occurred because of the number in string being too large to be represented in a `long`, `errno` will be set to `ERANGE` (it's in `errno.h`).

```
long rv=strtol(str, NULL, 10);
if(rv>INT_MAX || rv<INT_MIN || errno==ERANGE)
{
    perror("something is wrong.");
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I got it clearly. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) which according to the documentation states:

> If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains  only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed and zero is returned.

So as you can understand, your code has an invalid conversion.

Here are some sample codes that will work:

1. Correct use of `atoi`:

   ```
   char conv[20]="34";
   printf("score: %d\n",atoi(conv)); //this prints 'score: 34'
   ```
2. Using [`strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strpbrk):

   ```
   char conv[20]="score: 34";
   char breakset[] = "0123456789";
   printf("score: %d\n",atoi(strpbrk(conv, breakset))); //this prints 'score: 34'
   ```

Comment: that's C++ code.  The OP's question has a C tag on it, not C++.

Comment: @jwdonahue you are right, I've changed it to C code