# How are values passed into function without a parameter

Tags: c, global-variables

I couldn't figure out how the program works so I ran it on the computer and got the output:

```
the sum of 5 to 4 is 10
```

I do not understand how `nMax` is passed into the `sumInts` function (empty parameters) during function call however the value of `n` is taken from the global variable. That's the only way it `n` could increment into 5 and sum into 10.

thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sumInts();

int n=0;
int nMax = 0;
int sum = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc<2) {
        printf("Usage: ex2 7 \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    nMax = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (n=1;n<nMax;n++) {
        sumInts();
        printf("The sum from %d to %d is %d \n" , n , nMax, sum);
    }

    return 0;
}

void sumInts() {
    while (n<= nMax) {
    sum = sum+n;
    n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [don't use `atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: `nMax` is also global, just like `n`.

Answer (score 2):

`nMax` isn't actually passed into `sumInts` at all - it's what is known as a global variable. A global variable is a variable that is defined outside any function, can be used inside any function, and retains its value between function calls. Since `nMax` is global, setting it in the main function changes its value in `sumInts` and causes the program to run as you see. This is considered somewhat bad style in general though, and should probably be avoided to prevent bugs.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think i understand now. I just want to cofirm that its because when i assign argument value into nMax in the int main function has changed the global value of nMax into 4. Please correct me if im wrong 

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no parameter passing.

Besides, both `while` and `for` loops share the same global variables.

The `for (n=1;n<nMax;n++)` is useless since `while` loop makes `n<nMax` condition false after 1 call to `sumInts` (and the result is correct).

So a lot of redundant code here, and also using global variables (specially with names like `n`) will get you into trouble soon enough.