# Why is my program crashing when I try to print a char pointer

Tags: c

So i have this program for my C class its to make a function that will tell you the character at a certain number position in the string.

```
char charAt( char * string, int position );

int main( int argc, char * argv[ ] ) {

    int pos = atoi( argv[3] );

    if( strcmp( argv[1], "charAt" ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "%s", charAt( argv[2], pos ) );
    }    
}



char charAt( char *string, int position ){
    int count = 0;
    while( count != position ){
        string++;
        count++;
    }

    return *string;
}
```

When i compile it shows no errors when i run it in the command line using

```
name charAt string 3
```

It crashes at

```
printf( "%s", charAt( argv[2], pos) );
```

that line
Why when i pass the char pointer to the printf function does it crash?

Comment: Don't double tag questions as C and C++ *unless* it is specifically about those two languages (either trying to call one from the other or the differences in behavior)

Comment: This isn't c++; C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: note that [`atoi` shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: Change `while( count != position ){` to  `while(*string &&  count != position ){` to check that you do not go off the end of the string

Comment: You could also pack this whole function `chatAt()` into a single line: `char charAt(char *string, int position) { return string[position]; }`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Disagree... It's fine to use `atoi`, `gets`  and not check `argc` *for quick prototype programs* where you can clearly see what's going on and where nobody else is going to run your program.

Answer (score 13):

You're referencing `argv` without checking that `argc` is high enough to permit those references. What if `argc` is only `1`?

The real problem is using `%s` to display a single character. That needs to be `%c`. Using `%s` is going to treat that as a character *pointer*, which it isn't, and then your program is deep into *undefined behaviour*.