# Median Function In C

Tags: c

```
int findMedian (int argc, char** argv){

    int temp;
    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i) { /// bubble sort the array
        for(int j=i+1; j<argc ; ++j) {
            if(argv[i] > argv[j]) {
                temp = atoi(argv[i]);
                argv[i] = argv[j];
                *argv[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int Median;
    if(argc %2 == 0){///if is even amount of number, take the mean of middle two number

        Median= ((atoi(argv[argc / 2 ])+ atoi(argv[argc / 2 + 1])) /2);
    }
    else{ /// if is odd amount of number, take the middle number.
        Median = atoi(argv[argc / 2 + 1 ]);
    }
    return Median;
}
```

My median function will give me a median that is not sorted. anyone know why?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: At least this if statement if(argv[i] > argv[j]) { does not make sense. Ther are compied pointers themselves instead of the pointed values.

Answer (score 1):

First, you sort pointers to the string representations of numbers instead of numbers. Let's assume that your numbers are integer (since you use `atoi` and return an `int`). You should allocate an array of integers of the appropriate length, convert the strings into integers with `strtol()` in a loop, and store the integers into the array. Now, the data are ready for sorting.

*Note 1*: Do not use `atoi()` for conversion because it cannot tell a true 0 from a non-numeric string - unless you can guarantee that all the strings are valid representations of integer numbers.

*Note 2*: Since your function is meant to calculate the median of an array of integer numbers, make it take an array of integer numbers as a parameter. Do the conversion elsewhere (in the caller).

Finally, consider using `qsort()` instead of manually sorting the array. `qsort()` is known to work, unlike your code, and it is on average much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do a comparison like this, you'll have to do one of the following:

```
sscanf(argv[i], "%f", ...);
sscanf(argv[j], "%f", ...);
```

then compare the values from the scanf floats.

```
strcmp(argv[i], argv[j]);
stricmp(argv[i], argv[j]); // if your compiler requires it.
```

or some other derivative.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to sort an array of numbers, you need to convert string (char*) arguments to numbers first. Process argv** string array and convert each char* argument to integer with [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), or, better, [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function, filling new array of integers.

2) Having array of integers, you can sort them with library [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function.

Comment: note that [`atoi` shouldn't be used in serious contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: Should not, agree. This one is not a serious, I believe (?).
Using atoi as in the original code it should be assumed that all input is correct. Suggested "better, strtol".