# Stopping user input after Ctrl+D requires 2 presses; why?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, eof

A user can enter various different amounts of numbers (as long as they don't enter over 5000 numbers). However, when the user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the program should stop requesting user input. I've done this so far. However, I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice before it stops. Could someone help me to fix it?

```
int input_array[MAX_NUMBERS] = {0};

scanf("%d", &input_array[0]);

int eof_detector = getchar();

int i = 0;
while ((i < 5000) && (eof_detector != EOF)) {
    i++;
    scanf("%d", &input_array[i]);
    eof_detector = getchar();
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 I get a compiler error. Maybe I understood it wrong? Could you show me in whole what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more simpler solution.

```
// When the person presses CTRL+D, scanf will return EOF.
// Since the return value is EOF and not 1, it will break
// out of the scanning while loop.
// Also note, you can scan numbers as a while loop
// condition.
int input_array[MAX_NUMBERS] = {0};

int i = 0;
while (
       (scanf("%d", &input_array[0]) == 1) &&
       (i < MAX_NUMBERS)
      ) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you no need to use `getchar()` separately before loop & inside loop. use `getchar()` in condition & also `scanf()` will return `EOF` if it encounters *end of input* so check the *return value* of `scanf()`. Do like this

```
int main() {
        int input_array[MAX_NUMBERS] = {0};
        int i = 0,ret;

        do {
                ret = scanf("%d", &input_array[i]);/* if you pressed
                                              CTRL+D, scanf return EOF */
                if(ret == EOF)/* if ctrl+d pressed,condition becomes true */
                        break;
                i++;
        }while ((i < 5000) && (getchar() != EOF));/* it won't check this
                                             bcz of break statement if CTRL+d pressed */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: As expected. `scanf` will read once and `getchar` a second time. You need to get rid of `getchar` if you want to read only once.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim If I get rid of getchar how can I detect EOF?

Comment: Check my answer and the first comment to your question. `scanf` itself will return `EOF` it if encounters the end of input.

Comment: I modified  my answer @ZoeyMalkov check. As told by Noufal `Scanf()` itself will return `EOF` if it encounters end of input.

Comment: @achal I can't use the function do. I also don't know what it is. Is there a way to do it using an if statement or something?

Comment: `do` is not a `function`, its a `loop` called `do..while` loop & you can use, its best suitable for this scenario.

Comment: _Is there a way to do it using an if statement ?_ I shown above right ? check the return value of `scanf()`

Comment: @achal I don't quiet understand do, I can't use `do` either. Is do like a while loop within a while loop? Or is do, just saying do this when its in the loop? if its like this, couldn't I remove `do`  and place its conents within the while loop and the program will do the same thing?

Comment: `do..while` is one of iterative control statement, you can't separate `do` from `while` . just check the syntax of here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to encounter the `EOF` while in `scanf`, so what you should do is test the return value of `scanf` and when it fails call `feof(stdin)` to see whether the failure was due to an `EOF` or an error.

```
for(i=1;i<4999;i++){
   if(EOF==scanf("%d", &input_array[i])){
      if(feof(stdin)) /*EOF*/; else /*error*/;
      break;
   }
}
```

As the [scanf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) manpage indicates, scanf returns `EOF` on either an error (in which case `errno` is set to one of the values listed in the manpage) or `EOF`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sort of new to programming. What value does scanf return or show when it fails (so I can do the if statement for it). Also I can't use feof(stdin) because we haven't learnt it in class. We can only use things we learnt, which is like if statements

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov scanf returns EOF on error/EOF. It's in the manpage (or the standard). I've added the details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't use things like feof or break since I haven't learnt them. Is there any other way?

Comment: If Scanf returns EOF too, how can I write an if statement for that? would it be like `if (input_array[i] != EOF)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `getchar` separately to check whether EOF has been reached. `scanf` will itself return an `EOF` if it encounters the end of data. Your loop will work like so

```
  do {
      ret = scanf("%d", &input_array[i]);
      i++;
     } while ((i < 5000) && (ret != EOF));
```

Comment: I can't use functions like do. I don't know if ret is a function or not, but I can't use it. I can use things like if statements?

Comment: `ret` is an `int` variable. `do` is not a function. It's part of `C` and is a variant of `while` with the test at the end rather than the beginning. You can do this like you've done as well. Put one extra `scanf` and `if` test outside the loop. Then you can use a `while` instead.

Comment: if I use fgets, can fgets read integers as integers? Then somehow use atoi function?

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov [Don't use `atoi()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov The bottom line is to avoid using `getchar` and to rely on the return value of `scanf`. The rest is upto you.