# Pointer moving inside string

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm strudying this code but I'm not understanding how the pointer is moving inside of `buffer`

...

```
  while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL){  
    read_line_p = malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));   
    strcpy(read_line_p,buffer);   
    char *string_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(read_line_p,",");
    char *integer_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL,",");  

    char *string_field_1 = malloc((strlen(string_field_in_read_line_p)+1)*sizeof(char));
    char *string_field_2 = malloc((strlen(string_field_in_read_line_p)+1)*sizeof(char));  

    strcpy(string_field_1,string_field_in_read_line_p);
    strcpy(string_field_2,string_field_in_read_line_p);    
    int integer_field = atoi(integer_field_in_read_line_p);  

    struct record *record_p = malloc(sizeof(struct record));   
    record_p->string_field = string_field_1;
    record_p->integer_field = integer_field;

    ordered_array_add(array, (void*)record_p);

    free(read_line_p);
  }
```

...

The source code does this :

reads from a `.csv` file millions of records composed by a string and an integer which are separated by `,` and every record is placed on a different line; every record is added as a singol element into a generic array that we must order. The generic array is rappresented by

```
typedef struct {
  void** array; 
  unsigned long el_num; //index
  unsigned long array_capacity; //length
  int (*precedes)(void*,void*); //precedence relation (name of a function in main which denota which one field we're comparing)
}OrderedArray;
```

Inside of this struct we have the   precedes  function which tells us if we have to sort the array by the string field or by the integer field.

Example of records inside our csv file

firstword , 10

secondword , 9

thirdword, 8 
ecc..

So at each execution of `ordered_array_add` we will have inserted a new element in the array.

Follows `ordered_array_add`

```
void ordered_array_add(OrderedArray *ordered_array, void* element){
  if(element == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"add_ordered_array_element: element parameter cannot be NULL");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(ordered_array->el_num >= ordered_array->array_capacity){
    ordered_array->array = realloc(ordered_array->array,2*(ordered_array->array_capacity)*sizeof(void*));
    if(ordered_array->array == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"ordered_array_add: unable to reallocate memory to host the new element");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ordered_array->array_capacity = 2*ordered_array->array_capacity;
  }

  unsigned long index = get_index_to_insert(ordered_array, element);

  insert_element(ordered_array,element,index);

  (ordered_array->el_num)++;

}
```

I don't understand how the first loop scannes through the string `buffer` because i don't see any indexes in the mentioned loop.

I wrote a similar code to the first loop that I posted, the issue is that it stops after reading the first word from `buffer` while the code that I'm studying reads successfully the whole string

```
while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL) {
char *word = strtok(buffer, " ,.:");

    add(words_to_correct, word);
    words_to_correct->el_num = words_to_correct->el_num+1;
    printf("%s\n", word);

}
```

Comment: *I'm strudying this code but I'm not understanding how the pointer is moving inside of buffer* Well, first that's pretty horrible code.  `sizeof(char)` is one by definition so every use of it can be removed. And all but one of the `strcpy()` calls are unneeded. Whoever wrote that code needs an introduction to `strdup()`.  Finally, what exactly is your question?  What "pointer" are you referring to?

Comment: The code that I'm studying is done by my UNI professor ...... anyway i'll edit the question for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire first loop can be rewritten as:

```
while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL){  
    // note how sizeof() is used - that way if the type of
    // record_p changes, no changes to this code are needed
    struct record *record_p = malloc(sizeof(*record_p));   

    // no need at all for temporary copies of the strings
    record_p->string_field = strdup(strtok(buffer,","));
    record_p->integer_field = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));

    ordered_array_add(array, (void*)record_p);
  }
```

There's no need to call `malloc()` and `strcpy()` so many times - and that pair can be replaced with `strdup()` - that's both [POSIX-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) and [supported on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235454.aspx) so it's pretty widely available.

Of course, that code needs error checking and [it shouldn't be using `atoi()` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi), but as posted here it will duplicate your original functionality.

With the added benefit that you can actually tell what's going on.

Your code

```
while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL) {
char *word = strtok(buffer, " ,.:");

    add(words_to_correct, word);
    words_to_correct->el_num = words_to_correct->el_num+1;
    printf("%s\n", word);

}
```

will only process the first word in each line - you need to keep calling `strtok()` until it returns `NULL`, because [`strtok()` only returns one token](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html):

```
while(fgets(buffer,buf_size,fp) != NULL) {
    // trick to keep loop simple - start by using
    // buffer on the first loop iteration, then
    // set tmp to NULL so later iterations works too
    char *tmp = buffer;
    // loop until strtok() returns null
    for ( ;; )
    {
        // note use of tmp here
        char *word = strtok(tmp, " ,.:");

        // line is fully parsed - break this loop
        // and get the next line to parse
        if (word == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        // now set tmp to NULL so next strtok()
        // gets a NULL first parameter
        tmp = NULL;

        add(words_to_correct, word);
        words_to_correct->el_num = words_to_correct->el_num+1;
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }

}
```

Note also that I'm spreading things out and not trying to stuff as much code on each line.  That's usually a lot easier to read.

Comment: So if the string that i'm trying to scan is all on one line (by that i mean there aren't '\n') each time that i enter in the loop i will scan only the first word?

Comment: @ZenoRaiser Yes.  In your original code, you will only get the first word on each line.