# Returning pointers back to itself

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return-value, void-pointers

My coding assignments came with it's header file, meaning we need to use the same data types, and not vary anything.
There is a lot of pointers, (mainly a lot of void *). Meaning things are confusing, more than difficult.
we have to do a separate function, just to increment the value referenced by a pointer. But given the nature of program, I don't want to constantly make new pointers.

The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void* intal_create(const char* );
void* intal_increment(void* );

void *intal_create(const char* str)
{
    int a;
    a=atoi(str);
    return &a;
}

void *intal_increment(void *intal)
{
    int *a= (int *)intal;//new pointer;
    ++*a;
    //value referenced has been incremented;
    *(int *)intal=*a;
    return intal;
}

int main()
{
    int * x;// void * return a pointer, need a pointert to int to pick it up
    char *dummy;
    gets(dummy);
    x=(int *)intal_create(dummy);
    printf("integer return is %d\n",*(int *)x);
    printf("address stored is %p\n",(int *)x);
    x=(int *)intal_increment(x);
    printf("integer return is %d\n",*(int *)x);
    printf("address stored is %p\n",(int *)x);
}
```

I wanted x to be the parameter called, and also for it to store the return value. The printf address is merely for my understanding.

**The segmentation faults never end, and from my understanding, I'm just returning a pointer and asking a pointer to stop the return pointer**

Comment: `return &a;` is a bug. Local variables of functions stop existing when the function returns, and you cannot use any pointers to them

Comment: `gets(dummy);` is another bug (in multiple ways), this is probably the cause of your segmentation fault

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about stuff like this, you really need to up the warning options. `-Wall -Wextra` is good for gcc and clang.

Comment: Here `gets(dummy);` input is read to were `dummy` points, which is "nowhere". This invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour. From then on anything can happen, from seemingly working to crash.

Comment: The first problem is that you should not return a pointer when memory it points to  is in stack, suggest you to return a instead of return &a from the intal_create function. In addition to that for dummy you need to allocate memory. You are just creating pointer, memory is not allocated.

Comment: So how would you suggest I initialise "Dummy". and if I can't return the address of local variable a, is it better to return value and have a pointer's pointed value change? I apologise for the question being low-level, along with buggy code, I'm an electronics student and have never been the best at coding, All this was from an extra credit course that I took up

Comment: Assuming your maximum string input is of length 20, You can initialize as "char dummy[21] = {0};"

Comment: "*we have to do a separate function, just to increment the value referenced by a pointer.*" so why the call to `gets()` at all?

Comment: because another part specified by header file was "input string and convert it integer". void* intal_create(const char* str). It seems like, thanks to a character pointer, I can't actually do that. Since I can't create an array.

Comment: If you want return a pointer from the intal_create then you need to allocate memory in the heap by using malloc() function.

Comment: ... or define `a` as `static`, givning away thread safeness with this, which probably is not an issue in the OP's case.

Comment: Why can't you create an array?, without allocated memory where gets will store the input string? string is nothing but a char array with null character at the end.

Comment: the void* intal_create(const char* str) is really confusing me, am I supposed to create an array and initialise a pointer to it?

Comment: No, you can do this "int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));" and then assign the return value of atoi function to *a i.e "*a = atoi(str)" then return a.

Comment: got it Yadhunandana. Thanks a lot. Can I ask why that made such a difference?

Comment: You can accept my answer then. :-), variables allocated in stack(I mean inside the function) valid only inside the function. if you returning the pointer then you need to allocate in heap. As far as gets function is concerned, It will write the input value to location pointed by passed pointer.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714) @Yadhunandana you [shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), and [shouldn't use `atoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 0):

By incorporating all the comments. Mainly allocating memory to dummy before passing it gets() function and allocating memory in heap for the return pointer of intal_create.These two fixes solve the issue. Have a look at the following code for reference.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    void* intal_create(const char* );
    void* intal_increment(void* );

    void *intal_create(const char* str)
    {
        int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *a = atoi(str);
        return a;
    }

    void *intal_increment(void *intal)
    {
        //Here i am not allocating
        int *a = (int *)intal;//new pointer;
        (*a)++;
        return intal;
    }

int main()
{
    int * x;// void * return a pointer, need a pointert to int to pick it up
    char dummy[20] = {0};
    fgets(dummy,5,stdin);
    x = (int *)intal_create(dummy);
    printf("integer return is %d\n",*x);
    printf("address stored is %p\n",(void*)x);
    x=(int *)intal_increment(x);
    printf("integer return is %d\n",*x);
    printf("address stored is %p\n",(void *)x);
    //Make sure you deallocate the memory allocated in the intal_create function.
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: `gets()` is not C (any more). Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Also all these casts are useless. Just drop them.

Comment: And add casting where it *is* needed: The `p` conversion specifier is defined for `void*` **only**.

Comment: I didn't want to do lot changes to given sample, So i have modified only buggy parts .

Comment: Strictly speaking this `...  %p\n", x);` and this `... %p\n",(int *)x);` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: why ... %p\n", x); this invokes a undefined behavior?

Comment: "*why ... %p\n", x); this invokes a undefined behavior?*" See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221690/returning-pointers-back-to-itself#comment89424887_51222152

Comment: The C Standard says of `%p` that: ["The argument shall be a pointer to void,"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) and that ["if any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) You need `printf("address stored is %p\n",(void *) x);`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know.. I will update with the typecast type.

Comment: void * really is confusing. Thanks for the void* type cast advice. I've been personally struggling with maximising the efficiency/ benefits of using void *. I just realised that we also need addition of numbers larger than a hundred digits. And casting everything to int is an issue. Still trying to figure that out