# C++ "no match for 'operator-'" when converting char to int

Tags: c++, iostream

I am trying to take multiple lines of input from the user with each line containing two numbers separated by a space:

```
4 7
15 21
32 78
```

My code so far is:

```
vector<string> lines;
string line;
int m, n;
while (true) 
{
    cin >> line;

    if (line != "") 
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    else 
    {
        break;
    }
}
for (string i: lines) 
{
    istringstream iss(i);
    vector<string> results((istream_iterator<string>(iss)), istream_iterator<string>());

    if (typeid(results[0]).name() == "char") 
    {
        m = results[0] - '0';
    }
    else 
    {
        m = atoi(results[0]);
    }

    if (typeid(results[1]).name() == "string") 
    {
        n = results[1] - '0';
    }
    else 
    {
        n = atoi(results[1]);
    }

    calculate(m, n);
}
```

I get an error at the `m = results[0] - '0'`. It says

```
error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 
'__gnu_cxx:__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > 
>::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'char')
```

Is there anyway to fix this so each number on each line is separated into an integer variable?

Comment: `typeid` is completely misused here. `n=atoi(i.c_str())` is all you want here. The second number would be retrieved on the next iteration of course, unless you rewrote the `for` loop.

Comment: And even non-standard `atoi` can be replaced when you use `stringstream` properly since it allows to convert between text and number types easily.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: "`cin >> line;`" won't read a line of text but a word.

Comment: `results` is a vector of `string`, so `results[0]` is a `string`, not a `char`.  This is why you get the compilation error.

Comment: All the elements of a `vector<string>` are `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

I am no big fan of reading something from one stream just to stuff it into another.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

std::istream& eatws(std::istream &is)  // eats up whitespace until '\n' or EOF
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.peek()) != EOF && ch != '\n' &&
           std::isspace(static_cast<char unsigned>(ch)))  // don't pass negative
        is.get();                                         // values to isspace()
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;  // not a fan of variable names like m and n
               // or i and j next to each other either.
    bool empty_input{ false };

    while ((std::cin >> eatws) && (empty_input = std::cin.peek() == '\n') ||  // empty line
           (std::cin >> a >> b >> eatws) && std::cin.get() == '\n')  // valid imput
    {
        if (empty_input)
            break;

        std::cout << "Do something with " << a << " and " << b << ".\n";
    }

    if (!empty_input) {  // if we reach this point and the last input was not empty
        std::cerr << "Input error!\n\n";  // some garbage has been entered.
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `cin` will only read until it hits whitespace, so you only get the first number. Secondly, you can literally just do `cin >> m >> n` and let `cin` handle the string parsing, instead of trying to manually convert the strings to numbers and such. I guess if you are looking for an empty line to end the input, then you will want to do this:

```
vector<string> lines;
while (true) 
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    if (line != "") 
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    else 
    {
        break;
    }
}
for (string line: lines) 
{
    int m, n;
    istringstream iss(line);

    iss >> m >> n;

    calculate(m, n);
}
```

Comment: will `calculate()` with garbage if the input is flawed.

Comment: I believe it will throw an exception if two integers cannot be read from the string