# How to convert a Unix timestamp in a wstring to a formatted date in a char array

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

For starter, please bear with me as a newbie in C++

The end goal is to store the date in the format of DDMMYY, e.g. "120319", in a `char` array with 6 bytes.

For started, I have got a `wstring` that retrieves a Unix timestamp e.g. "155xxxxxxx".

```
std::wstring businessday = L"155xxxxxxx"
```

Then, I convert it to `wchar_t*`.

```
const wchar_t* wcs = businessday.c_str();
```

Afterwards, after declaring a char array of 10 bytes, I convert the `wchar_t*` to a multibyte string.

```
          char buffer[10];
          int ret;

          printf ("wchar_t string: %ls \n",wcs);

          ret = wcstombs ( buffer, wcs, sizeof(buffer) );
          if (ret==32) buffer[31]='\0';
          if (ret) printf ("multibyte string: %s \n",buffer);
```

So now the `char` array named `buffer` contains the Unix timestamp formatted string i.e. "155xxxxxxx".

How can I convert it to a `char` array of 6 bytes using a date format like DDMMYY, i.e. "120319"?

I'm using a pre-standard version of c++ (MS VC++ 6)

---

In response to [user4581301's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133762/9837301):

```
long myLong = std::stol( buffer );
time_t timet = (time_t)myLong;

std::string tz = "TZ=Asia/Singapore";
putenv(tz.data());
std::put_time(std::localtime(&timet), "%c %Z") ;


struct tm * timeinfo = &timet;

time (&timet);
timeinfo = localtime (&timet);

strftime (buffer,80,"%d%m%Y",timeinfo);
```

Comment: Why Visual C++ 6.0? That is ancient technology. That is not even C++03. It is _pre-standardisation_. Can you not upgrade to something from this millennium?

Comment: @JaMiT Not even C++03, and the phrase "an older version of C++" carries with it no useful information.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree. The OP should have been more precise. (You are aware that those are not my words, right? I copied that phrase from one of the OP's comments to user4581301's answer.) More precision would have made it easier to pick an appropriate tag.

Comment: why should it work in VC6? None of the current OSes can even run that ancient IDE. Also note that VC6 will suffer from y38k problem

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit since you've made the same false claim twice now, I will call you out on it. The phrase is not useless; it *does* carry useful information. Not much useful information, but some. It carries the information that answers should not require C++17 features, and that is useful. Hence my edit did improve the question. But, as usual, SO does not approve of incremental improvements -- the unwritten rule of don't try to make things better if you might fail to make them perfect. I'll probably get banned at some point for repeated violations.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way I can think of is to

1. parse the initial `std::wstring` into an integer of sufficient size with [`std::stol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::wcstol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol)
2. cast the the integer into a `time_t`
3. use [`std::localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) to convert the `time_t` into a `tm` structure
4. and finally use [`std::strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) to format the `tm` struct into the DDMMYY string.

This would result in a 7 byte `char` array because `strftime` will apply a null terminator. If you really must have a 6 byte array, `memcpy` the first six characters in the 7 character array into a six character array.

Comment: Also, I'm using an older version of c++, so std:stoi isn't supported

Comment: is there an other way to change the wsting to integer

Comment: @epiphany From [tag:c++]: _"Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C++ standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used."_ Please update your question and tags to indicate which version of C++ you are using. Otherwise answers will continue to assume C++17.

Comment: For older versions of c++: [`std::wcstol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol)

Answer (score 0):

Tested in VS 6.0:

```
char output[7];
std::wstring input = L"1552869062"; // 2019-03-17 20:31:02 MST
time_t tmp_time = wcstol(input.c_str(), NULL, 10); // _wtoi() works too
strftime(output, sizeof(output), "%d%m%y", localtime(&tmp_time));

output will contain: "170319"
```

Comment: `_wtoi()`, just like `atoi()`, is broken in design and [shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)