# Convert char to int with blank space in C

Tags: c, string, int

I have a char variable such as a = ' 123' or b = '\t123'. So how to convert them into integer? 
My problem is read form text file contains multi lines of char like a and b. I want to convert them and save to an array.
Here is my code:

```
int main(){
FILE *file_pid;
int i = 0;
int number[100];
char line[20];
    file_pid = fopen("pid.txt","r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file_pid) != NULL){
         number[i] = atoi(line);
         i++;
    } 
}
```

Edited: I solved my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: What is the target platform?  The use of multi-character literals is a relatively uncommon extension.

Comment: Just use `atoi()` or `strto(u)l()`, it will ignore leading whitespace

Comment: you mean _chr = " 123"_ or _chr = "\t123"_ probably

Comment: @Ctx atoi() didn't help.

Comment: @bruno both cases.

Comment: @ĐứcTuấnTrương Too bad. Maybe it would help if you showed a minimal compilable code snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Ctx I have edited

Comment: @ĐứcTuấnTrương The code has several issues, but looks mostly ok. It still isn't complete, however, how is "number" declared? How do you observe that it is not working, since there is no output?

Comment: Edit your question to show the contents of _pid.txt_ and the output when you execute your program. Note you do not check _fopen_ success

Comment: I have fixed it. How fool am I :))

Comment: @ĐứcTuấnTrương again **NEVER** use _atoi_ !

Comment: @bruno Above you write "use one of the atol functions or sscanf". So, how is atol better than atoi?

Comment: @Ctx sorry, typo, I wanted to say strtol, like in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `atoi()` function to directly convert a string into integer.
The C library function:

`int atoi(const char *str)` converts the string argument str to an integer.
This function returns the converted integral number as an int value. If no valid conversion could be performed, it returns zero.
good part is that it ignores spaces.

you might not want to store multi-character character constant in a character variable. Use character array instead example:

`char c[] = " 123";
printf("%d\n", atoi(c));`

Comment: is it required to store it in a character variable?

Comment: `atoi` is bad. Use `stoi` instead. [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)