# C++ regex replace with a callback function

Tags: c++, regex

I have a map that stores id to value mapping, an input string can contain a bunch of ids. I need to replace those ids with their corresponding values. For example:

```
string = "I am in #1 city, it is now #2 time" // (#1 and #2 are ids here)
id_to_val_map = {1 => "New York", 2 => "summer"}
```

Desired output:

```
"I am in New York city, it is now summer time"
```

Is there a way I can have a callback function (that takes in the matched string and returns the string to be used as replacement) ? `std::regex_replace` doesn't seem to support that.

The alternative is to find all the matches, then compute their replacement values, and then perform the actual replacement. Which won't be that efficient.

Comment: You can use `std::regex_replace`, but it seems like you have to use it multiple times. Honestly, I would parse string by hand if the holder value is actually `#1` and there can be no `#` anywhere else in the text.

Comment: regex then `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

Comment: Are you going to make replacements multiple times on the same template string (`string` in your example), or just one time per template?

Answer (score 3):

You might do:

```
const std::map<int, std::string> m = {{1, "New York"}, {2, "summer"}};
std::string s = "I am in #1 city, it is now #2 time";

for (const auto& [id, value] : m) {
    s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("#" + std::to_string(id)), value);
}
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/gLwYYu)

Answer (score 0):

A homegrown way is to use a while loop with regex_search() then
build the output string as you go.

This is essentially what *regex_replace()* does in a single pass.

No need to do a separate regex for each map item which has overhead of
reassignment on every item ( *s=regex_replace()* ) as well as covering the same
real estate with every pass.

Something like this regex

```
 (?s)
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 (?:
      \#
      ( \d+ )                       # (2)
   |  $
 )
```

with this code

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator SITR;
typedef std::smatch X_smatch;
#define REGEX_SEARCH std::regex_search

std::regex _Rx =  std::regex( "(?s)(.*?)(?:\\#(\\d+)|$)" );

SITR start = oldstr.begin();
SITR end   = oldstr.end();
X_smatch m;

std::string newstr = "";

while ( REGEX_SEARCH( start, end, m, _Rx ) )
{
    newstr.append( m[1].str() );

    if ( m[2].matched ) {
    {
        // append the map keys value here, do error checking etc..
        // std::string key = m[2].str();
        int ndx = std::atoi( m[2].str() );
        newstr.append( mymap[ ndx ] );
    }
    start = m[0].second;
}

// assign the old string with new string if need be
oldstr = newstr;
```

Comment: instead of `std::atoi( m[2].str() );` use `std::stoi( m[2] );` which is much better. See [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @phuclv The only speed benefit I can see is that since `std::stoi()` is using a reference to a string it has the advantage of knowing its length ahead of time and using that as a loop counter instead of atoi() which checks the contents for NULL or '\0' to determine the end of string. They both use a pointer and arithmatic to access the array of chars (ie. char*). And since `m[n].str()` will always return a fully qualified null terminated char ptr to it, the only error would be not a number NAN where the return value is always 0. Nothing to see here.

Comment: I also did notice that `std::stol()` is mostly replaced with `std::stoi()` as most compilers are for 64 bit registers making it 63 bits + sign. If you have a number that needs to be 64 bits, its for display purposes, not for calculation.

Comment: @Maxt8r not only you have a known length, you also don't have the undefined behavior that `atoi` exhibits. The code is also shorter and cleaner. And if you want unsigned then there are also `stoui/stoul/stoull`