# Why do I get "Non-standard syntax; use '&' to create pointer to member" and "no overloaded function takes 2 arguments" errors?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I'm getting these two errors in my code:

```
Error   C3867   'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member 59 
Error   C2661   'Product::Product': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments 59
```

It seems like when I'm trying to call my non-default constructor it's only getting 2 arguments even though I'm trying to pass it 4. This is just speculation, but I suspect maybe I need to add some NULL checkers or something? but I don't see how any of the arguments I'm passing it could be NULL so I'm stuck.

Here's my declaration and definition for my non-default constructor:

```
Product(bool restocking, string name, int quantity, double price); //Declaration
Product::Product(bool restocking, string name, int quantity, double price):InventoryItem(restocking), quantity_(quantity), price_(price) { } //Definition
```

Product is a derived from `InventoryItem`

Here's the troublesome piece of code:

```
void InventorySystem::BuildInventory(void) {
   int i{ 0 };
   string name_buffer;
   string quantity_buffer;
   string price_buffer;
   ifstream fin("in_inventory.txt");
   if (fin) {
      while (getline(fin, name_buffer, ';') && i < g_kMaxArray) {
         getline(fin, quantity_buffer, ';');
         getline(fin, price_buffer, '\n');
         p_item_list_[i] =  new Product(false, name_buffer, atoi(quantity_buffer.c_str), atof(price_buffer.c_str)); \\ Error on this line
         i++;
         item_count_++;
      }
   }
   else {
      cout << "Error: Failed to open input file." << endl;
   }
   fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Could be a `float` `double` mis-match.

Comment: Did you mean `.cstr()` instead of just `.cstr`?

Comment: use `stoi` and you don't need `.c_str()` anymore, and no more undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cstr() is a function, so make sure you call it to get the result (rather than treating as a member variable)

```cpp
         p_item_list_[i] =  new Product(false, name_buffer, atoi(quantity_buffer.c_str()), atof(price_buffer.c_str()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use empty parentheses to call a member function with no parameters:

```
... atoi(quantity_buffer.c_str()) ...
```

If the compiler sees `c_str` without parentheses, it makes a very unreasonable assumption that you want to refer to the function itself, using a pointer to it. This is a rarely-used feature.

To complicate the matters even more, there are two possible syntaxes for pointer to member function, and one of them is non-standard. This is what the compiler complains about. You don't need any of this, so add parentheses to tell the compiler that you want to call the function and not take a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

The pair `()` is the [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator). Without it you only get the [**function pointer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), no calls are made

But don't use `atoi()`. See [the reason why it should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714). Use [`stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead, and use [`stod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to get a double

```
p_item_list_[i] = new Product(false, name_buffer,
                              stoi(quantity_buffer), stod(price_buffer));
```

As you can see, the code is much cleaner because there's no `.c_str()` everywhere, as the `sto*` family receives `std::string` directly (which is much better than receiving a `const char*`)

Another note: don't use such a long lines. No one likes horizontal scrolling