# Why strtok() causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read file in c and store it in array. After that I need convert to integer related to input.
But I got segmentation fault. 
When I'm looking for reason then I realised that strtok() causes segmentation fault. I tried some of solutions but I could not do that.

My input file is like:

```
1:2:3:4:5:6
6:5:4:3:2:1
```

and I store it in array.

**Note that: I need to split it by ":" character. And every item must be digit.**

then my code is below:

```
char* line = arr[i];
int d = atoi(strtok(line, ":"));
for ( j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
    pushLinkedList(&tmp->P, d);
    d= atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));  /* This part causes segmentation fault.   */

}
```

How can i get rid of this fault?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can you be so sure that it's `strtok()` which is causing segmentation fault?

Compile and run this program and check the behaviour:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    atoi (NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

From [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) *[emphasis added]*:

> Return value
>
> Returns pointer to the beginning of the next token or **NULL** if there are no more tokens.

Look at these statements:

```
for ( j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
    pushLinkedList(&tmp->P, d);
    d= atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));
    .....
    .....
```

If `SIZE` is some value greater than `<number of tokens> - 1` then `strtok()` will return `NULL` for the n<sup>th</sup> iteration where `n` is equal to `<number of tokens>` in the string.

Since, you have not shown the value of `SIZE` in code posted, I believe it's greater than the number of tokens in the string processed in the loop. When  `strtok()` finds all the tokens in the given string then all future calls to `strtok()` will return a `NULL` pointer and this `NULL` pointer is passed to `atoi()` which is resulting in segmentation fault. You should check the `strtok()` return value and pass it to `atoi` only when it's not a `NULL`.

You can do:

```
int d;
char* line = arr[i];
char* tok = strtok(line, ":");
while (tok) {
    d = atoi(tok);
    pushLinkedList(&tmp->P, d);
    tok = strtok(NULL, ":");
}
```

Additional:
[Why you should not use `atoi()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi)

Comment: Yep, that's a good rewrite of the loop, though the jury is still out on `&tmp->P`, which may be right, but may be the source of the segfault -- no way to tell without a MCVE.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, `&tmp->P` could be source of the segfault but the OP is pointing out the `d = atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"))` statement as cause of segfault in the program comment. But, of course, a MCVE would have assured the cause of segfault.

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` isn't causing the segfault. `atoi` is, because you're passing it a null pointer. You need to check whether `strtok` returns a null pointer and break out of your loop if it does, rather than just blindly handing it to `atoi`.

Comment: strtok does not returns a null pointer in my code. But I do not know why it causes.

Comment: @YMG with the code you have showed us there is no way you can know if strtok returned a null pointer or not. So claiming "strtok does not returns a null pointer" is not something we can trust.