# I am using this code to print from text file but the program gives me "-1.#IND00"

Tags: c

I have a problem. I am using this code to print from text file but the program gives me a different number -such as `11732408.000000`- each time. However I don't get this problem when `ex` is integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char example[] ="123.12/456 ";
    double ex = atof(strtok(example, "/"));
    printf("%lf", ex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide examples of working and non-working input.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code that others can copy, run and reproduce the problem. Please ensure to include the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: I cannot exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: We can't run your code because it is incomplete. And we also don't know what is in your input file and so can't even check that the code is reading it correctly. And finally, you have given an incorrect output but we don't know what the expected correct output is. Please read the provided link on how to create a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: I need to get some numbers such as 44.5676. If I change from float to int I can get it but I need to get in double type.

Comment: Yes, but what does the input file look like? How is `line` declared? How was the file read into `line`? What is the code before this? In programming, the details really matter alot. The error could be in any of those steps. Thus with so much missing detail we can't effectively help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice about a good question. This is my first question and English is not my native language so I may not have been able to explain my problem completely. I edited the question and elaborated it, I hope it is understandable.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing a LOT, including the `#include` statements for the needed header files, a `main()` function AND the complete function that  contains this code snippet

Comment: when using `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) before trying to use the pointer returned by `strtok()`

Comment: the functions: `atoi()` and `atof()` do not step over leading spaces, so should be checking for that condition.  The function `strtok()` tends to skip over multiple/adjacent  'delimiters` so should watch for that kind of 'oops'.   Suggest (for debugging) to print each char array that is returned by `strtok()` so you will know exactly what is happening

Comment: [`atoi` shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714) (at least on non trusted input like files). Use `strtol` instead

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the question by simplifying it, I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem. Thank you for your helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

    char example[20]  ="123.12/456 ";
    double ex=atof(strtok(example,"/"));
    printf("%lf",ex);




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` which contains the declaration of `atof()`.

Your compiler is lenient and accepts your code is spite of the missing declaration, and it incorrectly infers the prototype to be `int atof(char *)`, which causes undefined behavior when storing the return value to `ex`.

Hence the bogus output.

Note also that the `l` in the format `%lf` is necessary for `scanf()` but ignored by `printf()` as `float` arguments are implicitly converted to `double` when passed to vararg functions.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char example[] = "123.12/456 ";
    char *p = strtok(example, "/");
    if (p != NULL) {
       double ex = atof(p);
       printf("%f\n", ex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```