# How to convert hex str to int?

Tags: c

How to convert str "0xfa" to int 0xfa, str "0x5c" to int 0x5c ?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

        char a[]="0xfa";
        char b[]="0x5c";
        int c=a;
        int d=b;
        
        //i have to get c to be 0xfa,and d to be 0x5c
        printf("%c%c\n",(char)c,(char)d);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: just google "convert hex string to char array"

Comment: Note that normal programs only return 1 if they failed, otherwise return 0, although this usually makes little practical difference unless you're using it as a terminal tool.

Answer (score 1):

A character, in C, **is** an int.

Here, however, you are trying to convert a *str with hex val* to hex int.

You should use `sscanf()` , and `%x` for the formatting.

**Or** `atoi()` , `strtol()`.

They are all designed for this exact purpose.

Comment: see [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Hmm... well , you people here keep worrying about `atoi()` while I go and use my `scanf()`.

Comment: "A character, in C, is an int." --> Not quite.  More like a `char`: (or `unsigned char`, `signed char`) C specifies "character" as single-byte character, bit representation that fits in a byte".