# What is the correct way to malloc space for this structure in C using strtok

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, structure

I have a structure containing pointers that I would like to populate from an array, both defined below.  I'm using strtok to split a string in the `elements` array and then take the individual values and put them in the relevant structure values.

I can split the string ok but the value that is populated into `eleNum` is wrong.  I appear to be getting a pointer value or something similar.  I'm also unsure if my memory allocations for the 3 fields (`eleNum, eleSym, eleName`) are correct.  They work for `eleSym` and `eleName` but I don't know if this is just luck or the right way of mallocing space for them.

```
typedef struct PTdef {
    int     *eleNum;
    char    *eleSym;
    char    *eleName;
} ptDB;

int main(void)
{
    ptDB    pt[118] = {};
    char    elements[][40] = {"1,H,Hydrogen"};
    
    char    *token;
    char    *eleDup = (char *)malloc(40);
    char    sep[] = ",";

    strcpy(eleDup, elements[0]);
    token = strtok(eleDup, sep);        

    pt[0].eleNum = malloc(sizeof(int));
    pt[0].eleSym = (char *)malloc(sizeof(token));
    pt[0].eleName = (char *)malloc(strlen(token));

    pt[0].eleNum = (int *)token;
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    strcpy(pt[0].eleSym, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    strcpy(pt[0].eleName, token);
```

Output should be.

```
pt[0].eleNum = 1.
pt[0].eleSym = H.
pt[0].eleName = Hydrogen.
```

Comment: when using `malloc` to get space for a string, the length you need is the length of the string, + 1 for the null terminator

Comment: `pt[0].eleNum = (int *)token` leaks memory.  Why are you storing a pointer at all?  In general, if you have to add pointer casts to make your program compile, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Indeed, even if correct, you'd be using several dozens of bytes to store 4 bytes for eleNum

Comment: @M.M many thanks for advice on Malloc.

Comment: @paddy many thanks for advice memory leaks

Answer (score 2):

The posted code has several problems, see the comments inlined below.

> ```
> typedef struct PTdef {
>     int     *eleNum;
>     char    *eleSym;
>     char    *eleName;
> } ptDB;
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     ptDB    pt[118] = {};
>     char    elements[][40] = {"1,H,Hydrogen"};
>
>     char    *token;
>     char    *eleDup = (char *)malloc(40);  // no need to cast the return of malloc
>                                            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/
>     char    sep[] = ",";
>
>     strcpy(eleDup, elements[0]);
>     token = strtok(eleDup, sep);           // now 'token' points to nul-terminated "1"
>
>     pt[0].eleNum = malloc(sizeof(int));    // 'eleNum' points to a newly allocated int
>
>     pt[0].eleSym = (char *)malloc(sizeof(token));  // allocates sizeof(char*) bytes
>                                                    // typically 4 bytes in 32-bit
>                                                    // or 8 bytes in 64-bit compiles
>                                                    // regardless of contents of 'token'
>
>     pt[0].eleName = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)); // allocates strlen("1") = 1 byte
>
>     pt[0].eleNum = (int *)token;            // discards the previous value of the pointer
>                                             // so it leaks the malloc(sizeof(int)) memory
>                                             // and forces 'eleNum' to point to string "1"
>                                             // which is not an 'int'
>
>     token = strtok(NULL, sep);              // now 'token' points to "H"
>     strcpy(pt[0].eleSym, token);            // copies nul-terminated "H"
>                                             // to oversized 4- or 8-byte buffer
>
>     token = strtok(NULL, sep);              // now 'token' points to "Hydrogen"
>     strcpy(pt[0].eleName, token);           // copies nul-terminated "Hydrogen"
>                                             // to 1-byte buffer, which overruns it
> ```

Keeping it as close to the original as possible, the following code would work correctly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct PTdef {
    int     eleNum;                   // store value, not pointer
    char    *eleSym;
    char    *eleName;
} ptDB;

int main()
{
    ptDB    pt[118] = {};
    char    elements[][40] = {"1,H,Hydrogen"};
    
    char    *token;
    char    eleDup[40];               // no need for dynamic allocation here
    char    sep[] = ",";

    strcpy(eleDup, elements[0]);
    token = strtok(eleDup, sep);        

    pt[0].eleNum = atoi(token);       // convert string "1" to integer 1

    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    pt[0].eleSym = strdup(token);     // or:  pt[0].eleSym = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
                                      //      strcpy(pt[0].eleSym, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, sep);
    pt[0].eleName = strdup(token);

    printf("num %d, sym '%s', name '%s'\n", pt[0].eleNum, pt[0].eleSym, pt[0].eleName);

    free(pt[0].eleName);              // cleanup
    free(pt[0].eleSym);

    return 0;
}
```

Left for the OP to fill-in:

- `strdup` return values should be checked to catch out-of-memory conditions;
- `strtok` return values should be checked to catch strings in the wrong format;
- `atoi` does not report errors, see [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi) and use  [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Comment: You may want to mention that `char elements[][40]` makes little sense for holding a single string.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Right, of course, and the same goes for `pt[118]` holding a single element. But I took OP's snippet to be just one step in some wider context, so I tried to flag and fix the critical issues, rather than attempt a comprehensive code review.

Comment: Yep, I could tell you were sticking close to the question, and there is know way to cover it all -- but I was still left looking at that with much bewilderment `:)` Presumably there will be more than one string.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin noted it would normally have 118 entries though.

Comment: @dxiv many thanks for your response it is greatly appreciated.  I still have much to learn re structure and pointers but you have helped a great deal.