# converting a char number into an int c

Tags: c, casting

So basically my problem is that i have the argv array from the stdin an if i type `./a.out 1`
i want to convert this **1** into an **int** or **long**, the problem is that if i do a cast into a long it converts the number into a random number and if i cast it to an int i get a warning and an error problably.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int j = (int) argv[1];
    printf("* j = %d\n",j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you _must_ check if `argv[1]` exists before applying any operations to it.

Comment: I know it exits the thing is how I do this

Comment: And I don't think that answers my question

Comment: you are casting argv[1] to an int.  It is not an int.  It is a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to:

```
int j = atoi(argv[1]);
```

you may have to also add to the top:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**EDIT**:
To satisfy these kids and their newfangled standard functions. ("validation" this and "undefined behavior" that... in my day, we made due with `atoi`!  And we were lucky to have it!)

```
char* endPtr;
long j = strtol(argv[1], &endPtr, 10);
printf("j = %ld\n", j);
```

Comment: see [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @phuclv, see edit