# convert string to double , the answer is correct ,but not very accurate

Tags: c, atof

I want to use atof to convert my string to a double，the answer is correct ,but not very accurate

**ATTENTION: because of some other reasons, fscanf is not permitted**

my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXCN 50

int main(void)
{   FILE* lstm_txt = NULL;
    char lstm_weight[MAXCN] = {0};
    int lstm = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float lstm_val;
    
    if ((lstm_txt = fopen("test1.txt", "r"))== NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"error:file open failed 'test1.txt'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((i + 1 < MAXCN) && ((lstm = fgetc(lstm_txt)) != ' ' ) && (lstm != EOF)){
        lstm_weight[i++] = lstm;
    }
    //lstm_weight[i] = 0;
    printf("\n lstm_weight: %s\n\n", lstm_weight);
    lstm_val = atof(lstm_weight);
    printf("\n convert \"lstm_weight\" to lstm_val is : %f\n\n", lstm_val);
    return 0;
 }
```

my file : lstm_txt is ：

4.217959344387054443e-01 -2.566376626491546631e-01 2.173236161470413208e-01 4.217959344387054443e-01

code hasn't bug, and the result is :

```
 lstm_weight: 4.217959344387054443e-01
 convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421796
```

**but I want Istm_val is 0.4217959344387054443** ,how can I do that?

Comment: 1) You're not getting 18 decimal digits of precision from a `double` on current architectures. You could try `long double` instead. 2) Read the manpage for `printf()`.

Comment: atof takes in a float not a double

Comment: `fscanf is not permitted` but why? it's a standard function and is available everywhere. The `ato*` family can invoke UB so they shouldn't be used. [*"If the converted value falls out of range of the return type, the return value is undefined"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof). See the reason [why `atoi()` shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714). The correct way to convert is [`strtof, strtod, strtold`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)

Comment: @phuclv The `scanf` functions have the same defect in their specification and shouldn't be used either.

Comment: @TruVortex_07 who said that? `atof` takes in a `char*` the represents a `double`. Did you read the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof)?

Comment: @zwol I already suggested `strod` above

Comment: @phuclv http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/?kw=atof, it says the parameters are a C-string beginning with the representation of a floating-point number. however i'm not really familiar with atof because i usually code in java or c++

Comment: @TruVortex_07 cplusplus.com is notoriously wrong and shouldn't be used. You can find lots of people pointing out that on SO. cppreference.com is maintained by professionals and is far more correct

Comment: @phuclv I was responding to your 'why isn't fscanf permitted?' query.  I don't know why it's not permitted for OP, but all of the `*scanf` functions are forbidden in every code base where I have anything to say about it, for the reason I gave (and several others, e.g. `scanf("%s", buffer)` is just as dangerous as `gets`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing `%.17f` you can have a precision up to `0.42179593443870544`

```
    printf("\n convert \"lstm_weight\" to lstm_val is : %.17f\n\n", lstm_val);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like `sprintf()`
here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    double n = 0.3984092590879;
    sprintf(str, "%lf", n);
    printf(str);
    return 0;
}
```

prints out:

```
0.3984092590879
```

Comment: there's no difference in printing with `sprintf` or `printf` or any functions in the `printf` family, the output is the same with the same format specifier. And there's no way to store more precisions than double is able to store

Comment: well he wanted a way to convert his double to string so and thats what he got

Answer (score 0):

A `double` typically has about 15 digits of decimal precision. You will not get more accuracy than that if you store the value in a double. You are getting less because you didn't tell `printf` how many digits of precision to use for output, so you got the default.

Use something like `%0.15f` instead of `%f`.

> convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.421795934438705

With `%0.20f`, I get:

> convert "lstm_weight" to lstm_val is : 0.42179593443870544434

That's the best you'll do with a `double`.