# Unexpected behavior with microchip xc16 compiler using builtin atoi function

Tags: c, microchip, atoi, xc16

Unexpected behavior of `atoi()` function. It is working in some part of my code and returning 0 in other parts, I am using the following code in different parts of application to find the bug.

MPLAB X IDE V5.4,
XC16 v1.61

```
 uint8_t result = 0;
 char test[] = {"33"};
  
 result = atoi(test);
```

Comment: `atoi`return an `int`not a `uint8_t`

Comment: [Don't use `atoi()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi)  It has absolutely no way to indicate an error, and if the input can't be represented as an `int`, using `atoi()` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Please show us a [example] that returns 0.

Comment: After doing some debugging and comparing with old stable version the only thing I was able to figure out was the size of file.  moving some code to other file solved the problem. strange. The Code Model was default [Small] may be this was the issue

Comment: What happens if you change the Code Model?

Comment: Changing code model didn't resolve the issue.