# Is there any difference in the way atof and strtod work?

Tags: c, atof, strtod

I know that `strtod()` and `atof()` functions are used for conversion from string to double.

But I can't figure out the difference between these two functions.

Is there any difference between these two functions, if yes then please let me know...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For one thing, they take different arguments.  Did you look at the man page for each of them?  Are you able to see that the arguments are different?  The answer is "yes", the two functions are different.

Comment: @TomKarzes I know that difference(number of arguments), I want to know other differences.

Comment: Then that's what you should have asked.  What you actually asked was "Is there any difference between these two functions, if yes then please let me know..."  I did just that.  There is nothing in your post that suggests you were aware of *any* differences between the two functions.

Comment: @TomKarzes Okay I apologize.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal consider rephrasing your question to make it a bit more clear. Like for example change your title to something like "Is there any difference in the way atof and strtod work?"

Comment: same as the difference between [`atol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) and [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol): the `ato*()` family has undefined behavior and `strto*()` doesn't. See [Why shouldn't I use `atoi()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [man page on `double atof(const char *nptr)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atof):

> The `atof()` function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to `double`. The behavior is the same as
>
> ```
>     strtod(nptr, NULL);
> ```
>
> except that `atof()` does not detect errors.

Why can't it detect errors? Well, because that second argument of [`double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3p.html) is used to point to the last character that couldn't be converted, so you can handle the situation accordingly. If the string has been successfully converted, `endptr` will point to `\0`. With `atof`, that's set to `NULL`, so there's no error handling.

An example of error handling with `strtod`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "1234.56";
    char *err_ptr;
    double d = strtod(str, &err_ptr);
    if (*err_ptr == '\0')
        printf("%lf\n", d);
    else
        puts("`str' is not a full number!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there any more differences left or that's all?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal from what I can tell, I believe that's about it. Feel free to do a bit of digging on your own though. If you find something, you can even post your own answer too ;)