# atoi() not converting whole string because of special character

Tags: c

I have data in my .txt file containing different time ins and time outs of employees. For example, `10:20` but I initially designed the structure to have their data types to be of char arrays or string. Since I'll be using the time values in another function, I have to use the atoi() function to convert them into integer values. Problem is, there is a colon `:` in each of the time values. Would it be possible to convert the string `10:20` to an integer using atoi() so that I can it in my future functions? Does the use of atoi() allow some splitting or some sort so that I can convert my time value from string to int?

I tried

```
char time[10] = "10:20";

int val;

printf("string val = %s, int value = %d", time, atoi(time));
```

But my output is only
`string val = 10:20, int value = 10` so only the string before the `:` is read and converted to string. I would want that after converting, I would stil have 10:20 as the result but in integer because I am going to use relational operators with it.

Comment: "I have to use the atio() function to convert them into integer values".  No, you don't.  In fact, you should never use `atoi`, since it produces undefined behavior on certain inputs.  Use `strtol`.

Comment: @Nic: What would you want the contents of `val` to be  when `time == "10:20"`?

Comment: What integer do you want to use to represent the string "10:20"?  Do you want to convert it to minutes past midnight, or seconds past midnight, or an epoch time incorporating the date, or something else?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Problem still persists regardless if I use strtol. My 10:20 string only becomes 10 after conversion.

Comment: `atoi(time)` == 10, `atoi(strchr(time, ':') + 1)` == 20 (I think, haven't tested), so you could maybe use 2 `atoi` calls.

Comment: @BillLynch Still 10:20, but in integers as I would need to use their values with relational operators

Comment: `strtol` will tell you the address of the character after `10`. Check if this is `':'`, go to the next character and from there use a second call to `strtol` to convert `20`. Or if the string can be modified, use `strtok` to split it into tokens delimited by `:`.

Comment: What integer should `10:20` become? `1020`?

Comment: `10:20` cannot be an integer as written. What are you trying to get out of the conversion?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes. Both William and mediocrevegetable's solutions work.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you actually want, but maybe something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char *time = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "10:20";
        int d;
        char *e;

        d = strtol(time, &e, 10);
        if( *e == ':' ){
                d *= 100;
                d += strtol(e + 1, &e, 10);
        }
        if( *e != '\0' ){
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("string val = %s, int value = %d\n", time, d);
        return 0;
}
```

This will produce `d = 1020` for the string "10:20".  It's not at all clear to me what integer you want to produce, but that seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this. This works for me. At the same time, mediocrevegetable1's solution also works while using atoi().

Comment: @Niic Be very wary of `atoi`.  No code written after the mid-90s or so should use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char const* time = "10:20";

  int h, m;
  if (sscanf(time, "%d:%d", &h, &m) != 2)
    return 1;

  printf("string val = %s, int value = %d\n", time, h * 100 + m);
}
```