# Apply atof to non-conventional scientific notation string

Tags: c, string, scientific-notation

Im building a parser which contains a regular definition that defines scientific notation like the example below.

```
char source[] = "+2.7+E10"
```

When i apply atof i don't get the result desired. Instead i get this: 2.700000

```
printf("%f",atof(source));
```

Is there any way to get the correct result with this string?

Comment: Use [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead?

Comment: That's not valid scientific notation, it should be `"+2.7E+10"`.

Comment: If you're building your own parser, presumably you will be able to extract the significand `+2.7` and exponent `10` parts yourself.  Then you can combine them using `x * pow(10, exp)` or the like.

Comment: [avoid the `ato*` family](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714). Use `strto*` instead

Comment: Since this is a nonstandard format, no, you're not going to be able to use a standard function like `atof`, `strtod`, or `scanf("%f")` to parse it.

Comment: Where this format is coming from at all? It does not make sense

Comment: Yes, you _can_ write a _wrapper_ function (e.g. `non_standard_strtod`) that strips the extraneous/erroneous extra `+` and copies and converts `+2.7+E10` into `+2.7E10` which _can_ be parsed by (e.g.) `strtod`. But, before you go too far down that rabbit hole, _what_ is forcing that format?