# Why I cant use atoi() function on a "string" instead of the char pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, atoi

I tried the following code and it is giving me error.

```
int main() {
    string String = "1235";
    int num = atoi(String);
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
/*
error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'
     int num = atoi(String);
                          ^
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2 
*/
```

But if I use the following code it works perfectly fine.

```
int main() {
    char* String = "1235";
    int num = atoi(String);
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
//prints out 1235
```

I know I can solve my problem using stoi() function.

```
int main() {
    string String = "1235";
    int num = stoi(String);
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
//prints out 1235
```

I can solve my problem by using a `char` pointer instead of `string`. But I just want to know why this can't be done by placing `string` itself into `atoi()`. How does `atoi()` work internally?

I just wanna know how does `atoi()` function work in C++

Comment: [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).  It requires a `const char *`, and a `std::string` is not a `const char *`.  Also `std::string` has a `c_str()` member function that gives you the `const char *` you're looking for.

Comment: Don't use `atoi()` at all. It will happily accept `atoi("my cow");` and silently return `0` with no indication of error... Use `stoi()`. See [std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: The direct answer to the question is (ignoring you shouldn't use `atoi()`) is `atoi(String.c_str())` passing the raw c-string from `String` to `atoi()` -- but don't do it.

Comment: Just different types. One function accepts `const char *` other `const string&`. And `string` doesn't have implicit conversion operator to `const char *`

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714), https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/03/13/atol-considered-harmful/

Comment: "I just want to know why this can't be done by placing string itself into atoi()" I don't understand the reasoning. Why should it be possible to do *anything* by just giving a string where the function asks you for `const char *` instead? Do you have the same question about `strcpy` or `strlen`, for example? Where the error message says "cannot convert", what was unclear about that?

Answer (score 1):

While `std::stoi` accepts `std::string` as input, `::atoi` does not.

Note: `std::string` is a c++ class type, `const char*` is a basic data type.   Although `std::string` does have a member function `.c_str()`, which can return its C-Style representation with `const char*` type.

Protype declarations of `std::stoi` in `<string>`:

```
int stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10 );
int stoi( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10);
```

Protype declaration of `::atoi` in `<stdlib.h>`:

```
int atoi (const char *__nptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `const char*` and `std::string` are incompatible, the implicit conversion
cause error.

If you still want to use `std:string`:

```
int main() {
    string String = "1235";
    int num = atoi(String.c_str());
    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see [this ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-string-class?view=msvc-170#c_str).