# Equivalent to atol() for numbers over long type (C language)

Tags: c

Is there a way to use atol() for numbers in strings bigger than the long type can store ?

Comment: There's `atoll` for `long long`, though `strtoll` is better.  Nothing else is standard, because types longer than `long long` aren't standard.  Note that `long long` is not necessarily any longer than `long`.

Comment: Sounds like you need a bignum library.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `atoi()`/`atol()` at all. They provide *zero error checking* and will happily return `0` for `atoi ("my cow");` without any indication an error has occurred. Instead for values of 64-bit or less, `strtol()` or `strtoll()` or their unsigned counterparts. Otherwise you can either use in-exact floating point conversions like `strtod()` or you need a big-numbers library.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 1):

For numbers outside the range of type `long`, you can use these standard functions defined in `<stdlib.h>`:

- `long long atoll(const char *s);`
- `unsigned long long atoull(const char *s);`
- `long long strtoll(const char *s, char **endp, int base);`
- `unsigned long long strtoull(const char *s, char **endp, int base);`

Using the `strxxx` versions is recommended to detect and handle overflow and invalid input.

For even larger numbers, you can use `double` or `long double` types, but the precision on the parsed value will be limited by the internal representation of these types, which have a much larger range and on most systems can also represent infinities:

- `double strtod(const char *s, char **endp);`
- `long double strtold(const char *s, char **endp);`

For more precision and/or integer range, you can use a bignum package such as the [GNU multiple precision arithmetic library](https://gmplib.org/), [GNU mpc](https://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/), [GNU mpfr](https://mpfr.loria.fr/) or the [LibBF](https://bellard.org/libbf/) used in [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/).

Comment: but `double` or `long double` may have less precision than `long`. And they still have finite range

Comment: @phuclv: `double` and `long double` do not have finite range, when IEEE-754 is used. They can represent values from −∞ to +∞. There is merely a large gap between the largest representable finite value and the next larger representable value.

Comment: *a large gap*... by an measure, that can hardly be reduced even with bignums :)