# type casting unsigned integer

Tags: c++, c

Consider `val` being a user input. I expect `val` to be between 0-65535

Instead of checking if `val` is not withing acceptable range before denying it, I was wondering if

is this :

```
uint16_t count = atoi(val);
```

the same as this :

```
uint16_t count = (uint16_t)atoi(val);
```

Is this an acceptable way of "securing" the user input? I do not intend to send a feedback to the user, I just want to make sure it won't explode if someone submits -123 or 999999. It does not matter if `count` equals `2` because someone submitted `65538`

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- yes, it's the same, unless you have a busybody compiler that insists on a cast because you might not have been smart enough to understand the first version of the code when you wrote it.

Comment: Note: `atoi` returns 0 on failure and 0 exists in your range of acceptable values. You may want to use [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) to get better error checking.

Comment: @WeatherVane ```val``` is an ascii. I would need to put it inside a ```uint32_t``` to perform meaningful tests. As I said, i do not intend to send user feedbacks. @user4581301 a fallback to zero in case of a failure is perfect in my case. Thank you all!

Comment: I deleted the comment after reading that you don't care whether the input value makes sense: only that it does not cause damage. Otherwise check its range *before* converting.

Comment: *Is this an acceptable way of "securing" the user input?* Totally depends on your definition of secure. No out-of range integer values will be processed, but if some something is consistently inputting garbage that's a sign of an error elsewhere in the system that needs to be investigated. Log it and someone will eventually thank you for the breadcrumb trail.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this:
>
> ```
> uint16_t count = atoi(val);
> ```
>
> The same as this:
>
> ```
> uint16_t count = (uint16_t)atoi(val);
> ```

They behave exactly the same. For the former, by assigning an `int` to a `uint16_t`, it is being implicitly converted anyway.

Since a `uint16_t` cannot contain any more than `65536` or less than `0`, the conversion safely stores the *modulus* of the `int` value in the `uint16_t` variable.

Comment: And the behavior is well-defined because unsigned integers perform modular arithmetic during the conversion.

Comment: Conversion to `uint16_t` wraps; it does not clamp. “Clamp” means that any out-of-range values are mapped to the nearer endpoint. E.g., any value less than zero would produces zero, and any value greater than 65,535 would produce 65,535.

Answer (score 1):

They are almost the same. The C standard’s specifications of how they will behave in execution are the same, and the C standard does not specify any difference between them other than the grammar, but neither does it require implementations to treat them identically in all regards.

For example, a compiler or code analyzer might warn you that `uint16_t count = atoi(val);` potentially alters a value during assignment while it lets `uint16_t count = (uint16_t)atoi(val);` pass without warning because a cast is usually taken as an indication that the programmer deliberately wants a conversion.