# cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Tags: c

[I keep getting these warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVsD.jpg)

I want to calculate the image size in colors in (Mo) and in black and white in (Ko) so for this I'm using a parameters that are past in a terminal command which are (image length and width)

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   
   float resultKo, resultMo;

   resultKo = ((int)argv[1] * (int)argv[2]) / (1024);
   resultMo = (((int)argv[1] * (int)argv[2])/(1024 * 1024))*3;

   printf("la taille de l'image en niveau de gris : %.2fko\n",resultKo);
   printf("la taille de l'image en couleur : %.2fMo", resultMo);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` has type `char *`.  There is no reason for you to cast that pointer to `int`.  That won't convert the string to an integer.  It will simply cast (and probably truncate) the value of the pointer itself.

Comment: Use the function ```atoi``` or ```strtol``` to convert numbers stored as text to an ```int``` or ```long int``` respectively.

Comment: Never use any element from `argv` unless you have checked `argc` first, to make sure the `argv` element is actually valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `char*` to an `int` in C, you don't cast the pointer. Instead you use [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

Comment: Note that `atoi` doesn't have any kind of validation. Better use `strtol` instead.

Comment: no [don't use atoi()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714). Use `strtol` instead